# Removing duplicate elements from an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, standard-library

I might have an array that looks like the following:

```
[1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
```

Or, really, any sequence of like-typed portions of data. What I want to do is ensure that there is only one of each identical element. For example, the above array would become:

```
[1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60]
```

Notice that the duplicates of 2, 6, and 15 were removed to ensure that there was only one of each identical element. Does Swift provide a way to do this easily, or will I have to do it myself?

Comment: The easiest way is to convert the array in an `NSSet`, NSSet is an unordered collection of objects, if need to keep order NSOrderedSet.

Comment: You could use the intersection function as you can find in this class with functions for arrays:
https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift/blob/master/ExSwift/Array.swift

Comment: Not part of Swift but I use Dollar. `$.uniq(array)` https://github.com/ankurp/Dollar#uniq---uniq

Comment: Probably the most elegant, smartest and fastest answer is provided by [mxcl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/5175709) below. Which also helps maintain order

Comment: Why don't you just use `Set` from Swift ? You'll be able to provide a list of unordered and unique elements.

Comment: I agree with @Andrea. You need to use NSOrderedSet if you want to remove duplicated elements in O(N) time and keep the order. NSOrderedSet holds a set and an array inside it: the set is for checking duplication, and the array is for keeping order. If you don't want to use NSOrderedSet, you can just use another Set for checking duplication. Hope this will help.

Comment: Apple finally realized this is a common problem and added their own solution in [swift-algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms). See [MH175's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68124738).

Comment: You can try uniqued() method. The uniqued() method returns a sequence, dropping duplicate elements from a sequence. The uniqued(on:) method does the same, using the result of the given closure to determine the "uniqueness" of each element.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You can roll your own, e.g. like this:

```
func unique<S : Sequence, T : Hashable>(source: S) -> [T] where S.Iterator.Element == T {
    var buffer = [T]()
    var added = Set<T>()
    for elem in source {
        if !added.contains(elem) {
            buffer.append(elem)
            added.insert(elem)
        }
    }
    return buffer
}

let vals = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
let uniqueVals = uniq(vals) // [1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60]
```

And as an extension for `Array`:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func uniqued() -> Array {
        var buffer = Array()
        var added = Set<Element>()
        for elem in self {
            if !added.contains(elem) {
                buffer.append(elem)
                added.insert(elem)
            }
        }
        return buffer
    }
}
```

Or more elegantly (Swift 4/5):

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    func uniqued() -> [Element] {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter { set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

Which would be used:

```
[1,2,4,2,1].uniqued()  // => [1,2,4]
```

Comment: You could also implement the body of that function as `var addedDict = [T:Bool](); return filter(source) { addedDict(true, forKey: $0) == nil }`

Comment: Very nice. Your solution will be my preferred approach for this kind of situations from now on.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Did you mean `updateValue(true, forKey: $0)...` instead of `addedDict(true, forKey: $0)...`

Comment: Oops yes sorry I accidentally the method!  Should be `return filter(source) { addedDict.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil }` as you say.

Comment: Is this answer, or converting it to a set faster?

Comment: Converting to a set, I suppose. I don't see how this one could possibly be faster, as it indeed adds each element to the set, with additional logic on top. But this approach preserves the initial order, which may be a necessity.

Comment: Just a word of caution: Avoid discussing performance for simple functions like this until you provably depend on their performance, at which point the only thing you should do is benchmark. Too often have I seen unmaintainable code or even less performant code due to making assumptions. :) Also, this is probably easier to grasp: `let uniques = Array(Set(vals))`

Comment: @Blixt Agreed. Once again, here the advantage lies in respecting the order of elements of the original array.

Comment: What would be safest way to define this method as extension of `SequenceType`? Does it need to be `mutating`? I tried myself, but failed :/

Comment: Why do you limit `T` to be `Hashable`? I'm assuming it's because if it's not `Hashable` you're not allowed to use on `Set`s. I'm trying to remove duplicates from an multi-demensional array, but since arrays aren't hashable...I'm thinking I should simply just append them to an array, rather than inserting. Obviously using sets are faster because it benefits from hashing...

Comment: i have [[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,3,4]] this kind of array so what i have to change in your code

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet @Blixt Some cursory benchmarking: For a large number of elements, observed all `Set` based variants to benchmark roughly the same - just minor differences over the implementations here (5-10%). Only the use of a `Dictionary` over `Set` benchmarks consistently slower (~0.5x). Release -O, swift 4.1

Comment: @Cœur I wrote that comment a while ago. Wouldn't it be better to limit it `Equatable`. That way it be more inclusive?

Comment: @Honey if you use `Equatable`, then you can't use a Set (you'd need an Array) and you lose in performances. So you should only add an `Equatable` overload if you really need it. I would be curious to know your use case.

Comment: @Cœur I don't remember my case. Merely pointing out that this implementation is restricting, but possibly more optimized.

Comment: I don't see any use of `Set<T>`

Comment: Converting to a set does NOT guarantee order.

Answer (score 675):

You can convert to a `Set` and back to an `Array` again quite easily:

```
let unique = Array(Set(originals))
```

This is **not** guaranteed to maintain the original order of the array.

Comment: Yup, after Swift 1.2, this is the way to roll this issue.

Comment: Is there a way to use a set while preserving the original order of the array?

Comment: @Crashalot See my answer.

Comment: If you need to keep the objects unique by a specific property, than also implement the Hashable and Equatable protocol on that class, instead of just using the Array->Set->Array transformation

Comment: What if you wanted to remove the duplicates altogether (rather than keeping one of them) ?

Comment: Nice!! What's the time complexity of this solution please?

Comment: Does this makes it change the original order?

Comment: For Swift3, I needed to set the type for the Set ... and make my struct conform to Hashable

Comment: This solution is simple but: You have to conform to equatable protocol. Changing Set to Array also doesn't guarantee keeping the same order of elements.

Comment: This probably doesn't preserve the order!

Comment: This gives problems on iOS 12

Comment: @RudolfJ What kind of problems?

Comment: Fails if the elements in `originals` are not `Hashable`; only `Hashable` data types can be added to a Set, yet any data type can be added to an array.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has so many upvotes. Seems like maintaining the order of the array is almost certainly a requirement. Otherwise you might as well just use a Set instead of an Array in the first place.

Comment: Based on the comments to this Answer, I do think the Ordered Set edit is quite essential... even if that's not explicitly asked in the question, that's likely what many/most people finding this page want. Good to have that related option in the high-voted answer rather than much further down the page.

Answer (score 125):

Swift 4

```
public extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func uniqued() -> [Element] {
        var seen = Set<Element>()
        return filter{ seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

---

every attempt to `insert` will also return a tuple: `(inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Set.Element)`. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1541375-insert).

Using the returned value means we can avoid doing more than one loop, so this is O(n).

Comment: After simple profiling, this method is really fast. Its hundreds times faster then using reduce( _: _:), or even reduce(into: _:)

Comment: @Kelvin Because all those other algorithm were `O(n^2)`, and nobody noticed.

Comment: @Kelvin this answer is identical to [Eneko Alonso answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797231/1033581) + my comment (Jun 16 '17).

Comment: Beware that duplicity is determined by Hash values of two objects/structs and not the `==` equality in `Equatable` protocol. If you want to determine duplicity lets say in struct hased only on some properties (not all properties), you need to use custom Hashable implementation with `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)`

Comment: We will use `Set<Element>(minimumCapacity: count)` initialiser in this answer.

Answer (score 94):

Use a `Set` or `NSOrderedSet` to remove duplicates, then convert back to an `Array`:

```
let uniqueUnordered = Array(Set(array))
let uniqueOrdered = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: array))
```

Comment: let uniqueOrderedNames = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: userNames)) as! [String] if u have array of String, not of Any

Comment: Fails if the elements in `array` are not `Hashable`; only `Hashable` data types can be added to a Set, yet any data type can be added to an array.

Comment: Tested in Swift 5.1b5, given that the elements are Hashable and a desire to retain ordering,  the NSOrderedSet(array: array).array is marginally faster than the pure swift func uniqued() using a set with filter.  I tested with 5100 strings that resulted in 13 unique values.

Comment: `Array(NSOrderedSet(array: array))` is not working in Swift 5. Use  `NSOrderedSet(array: array).array as! [String]` instead.

Comment: The second one only works for "primitive" types

Answer (score 82):

Many answers available here, but I missed this simple extension, suitable for Swift 2 and up:

```
extension Array where Element:Equatable {
    func removeDuplicates() -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()

        for value in self {
            if result.contains(value) == false {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Makes it super simple. Can be called like this:

```
let arrayOfInts = [2, 2, 4, 4]
print(arrayOfInts.removeDuplicates()) // Prints: [2, 4]
```

**Filtering based on properties**

To filter an array based on properties, you can use this method:

```
extension Array {

    func filterDuplicates(@noescape includeElement: (lhs:Element, rhs:Element) -> Bool) -> [Element]{
        var results = [Element]()

        forEach { (element) in
            let existingElements = results.filter {
                return includeElement(lhs: element, rhs: $0)
            }
            if existingElements.count == 0 {
                results.append(element)
            }
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

Which you can call as followed:

```
let filteredElements = myElements.filterDuplicates { $0.PropertyOne == $1.PropertyOne && $0.PropertyTwo == $1.PropertyTwo }
```

Comment: @Antoine Thank you for the Filtering based on properties extension. It's really useful. But can you please explain how it works. It's too hard to understand for me. Thank you

Comment: Updates for swift 3: func filterDuplicates(_ includeElement: (_ lhs:Element, _ rhs:Element) -> Bool) -> [Element]{

Comment: The first part of this answer (`extension Array where Element: Equatable`) is being superseded by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048862/1033581 which offers a more powerful solution (`extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Equatable`).

Comment: This will have `O(n²)` time performance, which is really bad for large arrays.

Comment: You should use a set to keep track of elements seen so far, to bring this terrible `O(n²)` complexity back down to `O(n)`

Answer (score 65):

If you put both extensions in your code, the faster `Hashable` version will be used when possible, and the `Equatable` version will be used as a fallback.

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
  /// The elements of the sequence, with duplicates removed.
  /// - Note: Has equivalent elements to `Set(self)`.
  var firstUniqueElements: [Element] {
    let getSelf: (Element) -> Element = \.self
    return firstUniqueElements(getSelf)
  }
}

public extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
  /// The elements of the sequence, with duplicates removed.
  /// - Note: Has equivalent elements to `Set(self)`.
  var firstUniqueElements: [Element] {
    let getSelf: (Element) -> Element = \.self
    return firstUniqueElements(getSelf)
  }
}

public extension Sequence {
  /// The elements of the sequences, with "duplicates" removed
  /// based on a closure.
  func firstUniqueElements<Hashable: Swift.Hashable>(
    _ getHashable: (Element) -> Hashable
  ) -> [Element] {
    var set: Set<Hashable> = []
    return filter { set.insert(getHashable($0)).inserted }
  }

  /// The elements of the sequence, with "duplicates" removed,
  /// based on a closure.
  func firstUniqueElements<Equatable: Swift.Equatable>(
    _ getEquatable: (Element) -> Equatable
  ) -> [Element] {
    reduce(into: []) { uniqueElements, element in
      if zip(
        uniqueElements.lazy.map(getEquatable),
        AnyIterator { [equatable = getEquatable(element)] in equatable }
      ).allSatisfy(!=) {
        uniqueElements.append(element)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If order isn't important, then you can always just use [this Set initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128846-init).

Comment: okay, got it. i wasnt able to call it because my array is an array of structs... how would i handle it in my case? struct of 20 different variables, string and [string]

Comment: @David Seek It sounds like you haven't made your strict hashable or equatable. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidSeek like this, uniqueArray = nonUniqueArray.uniqueElements

Comment: yeah dont worry. got it working right after. been almost 2 years now :P

Comment: This will have `O(n²)` time performance, which is really bad for large arrays.

Comment: The hahsable version will have better performance, but won't preserve the order of elements in the original array. Leo's answer will give both `O(n)` performance AND preserve object ordering.

Comment: More precisely, it preserves the original order of the array (whatever that is) and removes all but the first occurrence of duplicate items.

Comment: @Jessy There are already multiple `O(1)` answers, but they have way less votes than most of the naive `O(n^2)` solutions. This one is particularly good for its simplicity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234

Comment: @Alexander That requires `Hashable`. As I state in my answer, my `Hashable` implementation from Swift 3 translates directly to Swift 4. You need to include solutions for both `Hashable` and `Equatable` for the beginning of my answer to be accurate.

Answer (score 50):

edit/update **Swift 4 or later**

We can also extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol to allow it to be used with `StringProtocol` types as well:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {
    var orderedSet: Self {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter { set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
    mutating func removeDuplicates() {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        removeAll { !set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

---

```
let integers = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
let integersOrderedSet = integers.orderedSet // [1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60]
```

---

```
"abcdefabcghi".orderedSet  // "abcdefghi"
"abcdefabcghi".dropFirst(3).orderedSet // "defabcghi"
```

---

Mutating method:

```
var string = "abcdefabcghi"
string.removeDuplicates() 
string  //  "abcdefghi"

var substring = "abcdefabcdefghi".dropFirst(3)  // "defabcdefghi"
substring.removeDuplicates()
substring   // "defabcghi"
```

---

For **Swift 3** click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34712330/15)

Comment: I like this, it works with an array of dictionarys too!

Comment: @Alexander Leo Dabus has replaced the `reduce` implementation, so now the complexity is different.

Comment: What is the expression `.inserted` above? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @DuncanC it is the return value from the insert method.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1541375-insert  it returns a tuple. `(inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element)` if newMember was not contained in the set. If an element equal to newMember was already contained in the set, the method returns (false, oldMember), where oldMember is the element that was equal to newMember. In some cases, oldMember may be distinguishable from newMember by identity comparison or some other means.

Comment: Yup, I found it finally. That's very cool. What's the time complexity of your solution? At a glance I think it would be `n • log(n)`, since sets use hashes to determine membership. The naive solution of using array.contains yields `n^2` performance, which is **really** bad.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't know the complexity but I think it can't get any faster than that

Comment: I just did a quick test on 1m and 8m items, and it seems to run in `O(n)` time!

Comment: Which one is faster flatmap or filter ? Or is it the same?

Comment: The results are interesting. For both 1 million unique items and 8 million, the filter version is faster. However, the filter-based version takes 8.38x longer for 8 million unique items (a hair over `O(n)` time), where the flatmap-based version takes 7.47x longer for 8 million unique entries than 1 million, suggesting that the flatmap based version scales better. Somehow the flatmap based version does slightly better than `O(n)` time!

Comment: In fact, when I run the test with 64x more items in the array, the flatmap based version is faster.

Comment: @Jessy yes it keeps the original order. It is not called sortedSet. Btw it uses the same name Apple uses in `NSOrderedSet` just dropping the NS

Comment: "Original order" is an undefined concept, but wow, you are correct about Apple naming it wrong too. `NSOrderedSet(array: [1, 3, 2, 3])` does not enforce order; it's `[1, 3, 2]`.

Comment: kkkk Why do you think your way is correct? How would you name it? Note that this method it is not restricted to numbers. Its is constrained to Hashable not Comparable

Comment: @Jessy, `ordered` collection means that no matter how many times you gonna access it, it will have same order of elements. Like `Array`, each element will stay on it's place. For `Set` and `Dictionary` it's not true, if you will try to iterate over or print content you may have elements in different order each time. And that type of collections is called `unordered`.

Comment: @DuncanC a `filter { expression }` **is** a `flatmap { expression ? $0 : nil }`, so there shouldn't be any difference and I recommend `filter` for readability.

Answer (score 32):

**Swift 4**

Guaranteed to keep ordering.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func removingDuplicates() -> Array {
        return reduce(into: []) { result, element in
            if !result.contains(element) {
                result.append(element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this now, only changed the method name to removeDuplicates :)

Comment: I guess this solution is compact, but I believe that [deanWombourne solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048862/1033581) posted a year earlier may be **slightly more efficient** than a `reduce`: overall, it's just one more line in your whole project to write your function as: `var unique: [Iterator.Element] = [];
        for element in self where !unique.contains(element) {
            unique.append(element)
        }; return unique`. I admit I haven't tested the relative performances yet.

Comment: This will have `O(n²)` time performance, which is really bad for large arrays.

Comment: @NickGaens No it's not, it's `O(n²)`. There's nothing swift about this.

Comment: @Cœur `reduce` or `reduce(into:)` wouldn't make a critical difference. Rewriting this to not repeatedly call `contains` would make a MUCH bigger difference.

Comment: @Cœur Of course you can. It's actually quite simple. You just filter array elements according to whether or not you have seen them already (which you maintain using a set for `O(1)` `insert` and `contains`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234

Comment: @Alexander sorry, yes, I was distracted. I even found that solution BEFORE mxcl.

Comment: Yes, as many comments pointed out, this is not very time efficient and, if the Elements is also Hashable, other solutions are more efficient.

Answer (score 31):

Inspired by https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift, we can declare a more powerful tool that is able to filter for unicity on any keyPath. Thanks to Alexander comments on various answers regarding complexity, the below solutions should be near optimal.

#### Non-mutating solution

We extend with a function that is able to filter for unicity on any keyPath:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    /// Returns a collection containing, in order, the first instances of
    /// elements of the sequence that compare equally for the keyPath.
    func unique<T: Hashable>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> Self {
        var unique = Set<T>()
        return filter { unique.insert($0[keyPath: keyPath]).inserted }
    }
}
```

Note: in the case where your object doesn't conform to RangeReplaceableCollection, but does conform to Sequence, you can have this additional extension, but the return type will always be an Array:

```
extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array containing, in order, the first instances of
    /// elements of the sequence that compare equally for the keyPath.
    func unique<T: Hashable>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] {
        var unique = Set<T>()
        return filter { unique.insert($0[keyPath: keyPath]).inserted }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

If we want unicity for elements themselves, as in the question, we use the keyPath `\.self`:

```
let a = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
let b = a.unique(for: \.self)
/* b is [1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60] */
```

If we want unicity for something else (like for the `id` of a collection of objects) then we use the keyPath of our choice:

```
let a = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2)]
let b = a.unique(for: \.y)
/* b is [{x 1 y 1}, {x 1 y 2}] */
```

---

#### Mutating solution

We extend with a mutating function that is able to filter for unicity on any keyPath:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    /// Keeps only, in order, the first instances of
    /// elements of the collection that compare equally for the keyPath.
    mutating func uniqueInPlace<T: Hashable>(for keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) {
        var unique = Set<T>()
        removeAll { !unique.insert($0[keyPath: keyPath]).inserted }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

If we want unicity for elements themselves, as in the question, we use the keyPath `\.self`:

```
var a = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
a.uniqueInPlace(for: \.self)
/* a is [1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60] */
```

If we want unicity for something else (like for the `id` of a collection of objects) then we use the keyPath of our choice:

```
var a = [CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2)]
a.uniqueInPlace(for: \.y)
/* a is [{x 1 y 1}, {x 1 y 2}] */
```

Comment: Now that's a good implementation! I only with that key paths were convertible to closures, so that you can use a closure arg to support both arbitrary code (in closures) and mere property look ups (via key paths). Only change I would make is to make `keyPath` default to `\.self`, because that's probably the majority of use cases.

Comment: @Alexander I tried to default to Self, but then I would need to make `Element` always `Hashable`. An alternative to a default value is adding a simple overload without parameters: `extension Sequence where Element: Hashable { func unique() { ... } }`

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense!

Comment: Brilliant ... simple, and best of all 'flexible'.  Thx.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: This looks very similar to your own solution from March 2018: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/fbba1e58c91fbd4b5b767bcf8586112b 

Comment: Ah, @FizzBuzz, that's a good find. Congrats to Martin R and Alexander for being, like John Sundell, avant-gardists of those techniques.

Comment: @FizzBuzz I have no idea how you found that, but that's been kind of interesting to see. I forget that all this random crap I put out on the internet sticks around and get eventually seened by people. I can only hope it helped :p

Answer (score 28):

Here's a category on `SequenceType` which preserves the original order of the array, but uses a `Set` to do the `contains` lookups to avoid the `O(n)` cost on Array's `contains(_:)` method.

```
public extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {

    /// Return the sequence with all duplicates removed.
    ///
    /// i.e. `[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 ].uniqued() == [ 1, 2, 3 ]`
    ///
    /// - note: Taken from stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234, as 
    ///         per @Alexander's comment.
    func uniqued() -> [Element] {
        var seen = Set<Element>()
        return self.filter { seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

If you aren't Hashable or Equatable, you can pass in a predicate to do the equality check:

```
extension Sequence {

    /// Return the sequence with all duplicates removed.
    ///
    /// Duplicate, in this case, is defined as returning `true` from `comparator`.
    ///
    /// - note: Taken from stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234
    func uniqued(comparator: @escaping (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element] {
        var buffer: [Element] = []

        for element in self {
            // If element is already in buffer, skip to the next element
            if try buffer.contains(where: { try comparator(element, $0) }) {
                continue
            }

            buffer.append(element)
        }

        return buffer
    }
}
```

Now, if you don't have Hashable, but *are* Equatable, you can use this method:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {

    /// Return the sequence with all duplicates removed.
    ///
    /// i.e. `[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 ].uniqued() == [ 1, 2, 3 ]`
    ///
    /// - note: Taken from stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234
    func uniqued() -> [Element] {
        return self.uniqued(comparator: ==)
    }
}
```

Finally, you can add a key path version of uniqued like this:

````
extension Sequence {

    /// Returns the sequence with duplicate elements removed, performing the comparison using the property at
    /// the supplied keypath.
    ///
    /// i.e.
    ///
    /// ```
    /// [
    ///   MyStruct(value: "Hello"),
    ///   MyStruct(value: "Hello"),
    ///   MyStruct(value: "World")
    ///  ].uniqued(\.value)
    /// ```
    /// would result in
    ///
    /// ```
    /// [
    ///   MyStruct(value: "Hello"),
    ///   MyStruct(value: "World")
    /// ]
    /// ```
    ///
    /// - note: Taken from stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234
    ///
    func uniqued<T: Equatable>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] {
        self.uniqued { $0[keyPath: keyPath] == $1[keyPath: keyPath] }
    }
}
````

You can stick both of these into your app, Swift will choose the right one depending on your sequence's `Iterator.Element` type.

---

For El Capitan, you can extend this method to include multiple keypaths like this:

````swift
    /// Returns the sequence with duplicate elements removed, performing the comparison using the property at
    /// the supplied keypaths.
    ///
    /// i.e.
    ///
    /// ```
    /// [
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "Paula"),
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "Paula"),
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "Bean"),
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "World", value2: "Sigh")
    ///  ].uniqued(\.value1, \.value2)
    /// ```
    /// would result in
    ///
    /// ```
    /// [
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "Paula"),
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "Hello", value2: "Bean"),
    ///   MyStruct(value1: "World", value2: "Sigh")
    /// ]
    /// ```
    ///
    /// - note: Taken from stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234
    ///
    func uniqued<T: Equatable, U: Equatable>(_ keyPath1: KeyPath<Element, T>, _ keyPath2: KeyPath<Element, U>) -> [Element] {
        self.uniqued {
            $0[keyPath: keyPath1] == $1[keyPath: keyPath1] && $0[keyPath: keyPath2] == $1[keyPath: keyPath2]
        }
    }
````

but (imho) you're probably better off just passing in your own block to `self.uniqued`.

Comment: Heyyy finally someone with an `O(n)` solution. You can combine the "check" and "insert" set operations into one, by the way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234

Comment: Oh, that's clever :)

Comment: @deanWombourne How to distinct elements by multiple keypaths?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 You can just extend the uniqued method to take two generic parameters and check them both for equality - check out the edit I just made. The items are only duplicates if _both_ of the values specified by the keypaths are the same.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @deanWombourne

Answer (score 27):

## No need to write any extensions.

Apple has finally introduced `uniqued()` method in its Algorithms package.

Points to consider:

1. Not just Arrays. It can be used on any type conforming to `Sequence` protocol.
2. The Element type in Sequence must conform to `Hashable` protocol

---

Example:

```swift
import Algorithms

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
print(numbers.uniqued()) // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

More info https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Unique.md

Comment: Algorithms not from Apple i guess.

Comment: @UmitKaya It is absolutely from Apple, just published as a separate package to avoid littering `Foundation`.

Comment: Note that this still requires that the elements conform to `Hashable`

Answer (score 16):

Think like a functional programmer :)

To filter the list based on whether the element has already occurred, you need the index. You can use `enumerated` to get the index and `map` to return to the list of values.

```
let unique = myArray
    .enumerated()
    .filter{ myArray.firstIndex(of: $0.1) == $0.0 }
    .map{ $0.1 }
```

This guarantees the order. If you don't mind about the order then the existing answer of `Array(Set(myArray))` is simpler and probably more efficient.

---

**UPDATE: Some notes on efficiency and correctness**

A few people have commented on the efficiency. I'm definitely in the school of writing correct and simple code first and then figuring out bottlenecks later, though I appreciate it's debatable whether this is clearer than `Array(Set(array))`.

This method is a lot slower than `Array(Set(array))`. As noted in comments, it does preserve order and works on elements that aren't Hashable.

However, @Alain T's method also preserves order and is also a lot faster. So unless your element type is not hashable, or you just need a quick one liner, then I'd suggest going with their solution.

Here are a few tests on a MacBook Pro (2014) on Xcode 11.3.1 (Swift 5.1) in Release mode.

The profiler function and two methods to compare:

```
func printTimeElapsed(title:String, operation:()->()) {
    var totalTime = 0.0
    for _ in (0..<1000) {
        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        operation()
        let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        totalTime += timeElapsed
    }
    let meanTime = totalTime / 1000
    print("Mean time for \(title): \(meanTime) s")
}

func method1<T: Hashable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    return Array(Set(array))
}

func method2<T: Equatable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>{
    return array
    .enumerated()
    .filter{ array.firstIndex(of: $0.1) == $0.0 }
    .map{ $0.1 }
}

// Alain T.'s answer (adapted)
func method3<T: Hashable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    var uniqueKeys = Set<T>()
    return array.filter{uniqueKeys.insert($0).inserted}
}
```

And a small variety of test inputs:

```
func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}

let shortIntList = (0..<100).map{_ in Int.random(in: 0..<100) }
let longIntList = (0..<10000).map{_ in Int.random(in: 0..<10000) }
let longIntListManyRepetitions = (0..<10000).map{_ in Int.random(in: 0..<100) }
let longStringList = (0..<10000).map{_ in randomString(1000)}
let longMegaStringList = (0..<10000).map{_ in randomString(10000)}
```

Gives as output:

```
Mean time for method1 on shortIntList: 2.7358531951904296e-06 s
Mean time for method2 on shortIntList: 4.910230636596679e-06 s
Mean time for method3 on shortIntList: 6.417632102966309e-06 s
Mean time for method1 on longIntList: 0.0002518167495727539 s
Mean time for method2 on longIntList: 0.021718120217323302 s
Mean time for method3 on longIntList: 0.0005312927961349487 s
Mean time for method1 on longIntListManyRepetitions: 0.00014377200603485108 s
Mean time for method2 on longIntListManyRepetitions: 0.0007293639183044434 s
Mean time for method3 on longIntListManyRepetitions: 0.0001843773126602173 s
Mean time for method1 on longStringList: 0.007168249964714051 s
Mean time for method2 on longStringList: 0.9114790915250778 s
Mean time for method3 on longStringList: 0.015888616919517515 s
Mean time for method1 on longMegaStringList: 0.0525397013425827 s
Mean time for method2 on longMegaStringList: 1.111266262292862 s
Mean time for method3 on longMegaStringList: 0.11214958941936493 s
```

Comment: unlike `Array(Set(myArray))`, this works for things that aren't `Hashable`

Comment: ... and unlike `Array(Set(myArray))` the order of your array is maintained.

Comment: It looks like the best answer to me, at least at the present when Swift 5 is already the current version.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution; unfortunately, it's also rather slow.

Comment: This is really slow. If you wanted to keep the last of each element, you would be better users a better implementation, and doing `array.reversed().unique().reversed()`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don't understand your suggestion of `array.reversed().unique().reversed()`. The above solution keeps the first rather than the last of each element, and as far as I know there is no `unique()` method - that is the whole point of the question. Anyway, I don't doubt it's probably not the fastest method but unless it's in a performance sensitive place I'd go with readability and clarity of correctness over optimisation.

Comment: @TimMB Oh I misread your post. I saw someone's adaptation that usedthe `lastIndex(of:)`. I totally disagree over the clarity vs optimization point in this case. I don't think this implementation is particularly clear, especially compared to a simple set-based solution. In any case, such code should be extracted out to an extension function. This algorithm becomes basically unusable at even a low input size, like in the thousands to tens of thousands. It's not hard to find such data sets, people can have thousands of songs, files, contacts, etc.

Comment: @TimMB You can achieve the same goal of uniquing non-Hashable elements, keeping the first ones, by using `Array` for `contains` checks, similar to how the set is being used. That removes the need for enumerated (which doesn't really cost much) and the final `map` call (which does one full sweep of the full array). Furthermore, you can use `.reserveCapacity` on the set/array, to tradeoff some extra memory use for removing the need for reallocations mid-way through the algorithm.

Comment: @TimMB Other things to consider: `method3` allows for an implementation that removes elements inline from the existing buffer using `removeAll`, which isn't possible with methods 1 or 2. Method 2 and 3 are also generalizable to sequences that aren't `Collection` (which might not be re-iterable)

Comment: Check out my bench mark results: https://drive.google.com/a/ryerson.ca/file/d/1u4pnGS8dyNp4nIHup3irEFFoCy838i93/view?usp=sharing full code: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/299d012dccba375bf15880355684ebed

Comment: This is absolute gold

Comment: It should be noted that the fastest solution (after an unsorted set) might be indeed Alain T. approach together your addition of `reserveCapacity` as linked in the gist.

Answer (score 13):

An alternate (if not optimal) solution from [here](http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/pure-swift-little-deeper-into-generics.html) using immutable types rather than variables:

```
func deleteDuplicates<S: ExtensibleCollectionType where S.Generator.Element: Equatable>(seq:S)-> S {
    let s = reduce(seq, S()){
        ac, x in contains(ac,x) ? ac : ac + [x]
    }
    return s
}
```

Included to contrast Jean-Pillippe's imperative approach with a functional approach.

As a bonus this function works with strings as well as arrays!

**Edit:** This answer was written in 2014 for Swift 1.0 (before `Set` was available in Swift). It doesn't require Hashable conformance & runs in quadratic time.

Comment: Beware, there are not one, but two ways this runs in quadratic time – both `contains` and array append run in O(n).  Though it does have the benefit of only requiring equatable, not hashable.

Comment: this is a really complicated way of writing `filter`. It's O(n^2) (which is required if you don't want to require `Hashable` conformance), but you should at least call that out explicitly

Answer (score 13):

One more Swift 3.0 solution to remove duplicates from an array. This solution improves on many other solutions already proposed by:

- Preserving the order of the elements in the input array
- Linear complexity O(n): single pass filter O(n) + set insertion O(1)

Given the integer array:

```
let numberArray = [10, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 12, 2, 5, 5, 6, 10, 7, 8, 3, 3, 45, 5, 15, 6, 7, 8, 7]
```

Functional code:

```
func orderedSet<T: Hashable>(array: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    var unique = Set<T>()
    return array.filter { element in
        return unique.insert(element).inserted
    }
}

orderedSet(array: numberArray)  // [10, 1, 2, 3, 15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 8, 45]
```

Array extension code:

```
extension Array where Element:Hashable {
    var orderedSet: Array {
        var unique = Set<Element>()
        return filter { element in
            return unique.insert(element).inserted
        }
    }
}

numberArray.orderedSet // [10, 1, 2, 3, 15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 8, 45]
```

This code takes advantage of the result returned by the `insert` operation on `Set`, which executes on `O(1)`, and returns a tuple indicating if the item was inserted or if it already existed in the set.

If the item was in the set, `filter` will exclude it from the final result.

Comment: Not to be picky but you will be performing the insert and the membership test as many times as there are elements so you should count their cost as O(n) as well.  This doesn't mean 3xO(n) however because these O's and don't have equal cost with the filter so the addition of O(n)'s is apples to oranges.  If we consider set operations to be a O(1) part of the filter cost, the complexity is merely O(n), albeit with a larger "O".     Pushing this to the limit, you could also avoid the insertions when the element is already in the set.

Comment: You are right, using `defer` the code would do the set test operation twice, one with `contains` and one with `insert`. Further reading Swift documentation, I found that `insert` returns a tuple indicating if the element was inserted or not, so I've simplified the code removing the `contains` check.

Comment: Nice. Your extension could be optimal by doing it on `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable { ... }`

Comment: @AlainT. Nope. Both `insert` and `contains` have `O(1)` complexity. `O(1) + O(1) = O(1)`. These two operations are then done `n` times (once per call of the closure passed to `filter`, which is called once per element) I.e. if an operation takes a constant amount of time regardless of input size, then doing it twice still makes it take a constant time that is regardless of input size. The total complexity of this is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 13):

## Swift 5

```swift
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Element] {
        NSOrderedSet(array: self as! [Any]).array as! [Element]
    }
}
```

Comment: I did some variation so I could select a key to compare.

`extension Sequence {
    // Returns distinct elements based on a key value.
    func distinct<key: Hashable>(by: ((_ el: Iterator.Element) -> key)) -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var existing = Set<key>()
        return self.filter { existing.insert(by($0)).inserted }
    }
}`

Comment: There no need to use a `Bool`, when the only value you use is `true`. You're reaching for a "unit type" (a type with only one possible value). Swift's unit type is `Void`, whose only value is `()` (a.k.a. the empty tuple). So you can just use `[T: Void]`. Though you shouldn't do that, because you've basically just invented `Set`. Use `Set` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/3141234 Please delete this answer.

Comment: if your element is Hasable, you can directly use `Array(Set(yourElements)`

Comment: This changes the order of the array.

Answer (score 11):

## swift 2

with ***uniq*** function  answer:

```
func uniq<S: SequenceType, E: Hashable where E==S.Generator.Element>(source: S) -> [E] {
    var seen: [E:Bool] = [:]
    return source.filter({ (v) -> Bool in
        return seen.updateValue(true, forKey: v) == nil
    })
}
```

use:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9]
print(uniq(test)) //1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: The `Bool` value obviously is redundant, as your code never reads it. Use a `Set` instead of a `Dictionary` and you get my upvote.

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 5

```
 var array: [String] =  ["Aman", "Sumit", "Aman", "Sumit", "Mohan", "Mohan", "Amit"]

 let uniq = Array(Set(array))
 print(uniq)
```

Output Will be

```
 ["Sumit", "Mohan", "Amit", "Aman"]
```

Comment: This is a repeat of many of the answers already here, and it doesn't preserve ordering.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4.x:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
  func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
    return Array(Set<Iterator.Element>(self))
  }

  func uniqueOrdered() -> [Iterator.Element] {
    return reduce([Iterator.Element]()) { $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] }
  }
}
```

usage:

```
["Ljubljana", "London", "Los Angeles", "Ljubljana"].unique()
```

or

```
["Ljubljana", "London", "Los Angeles", "Ljubljana"].uniqueOrdered()
```

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`. Don't do this.

Answer (score 8):

For arrays where the elements are neither Hashable nor Comparable (e.g. complex objects, dictionaries or structs), this extension provides a generalized way  to remove duplicates:

```
extension Array
{
   func filterDuplicate<T:Hashable>(_ keyValue:(Element)->T) -> [Element]
   {
      var uniqueKeys = Set<T>()
      return filter{uniqueKeys.insert(keyValue($0)).inserted}
   }

   func filterDuplicate<T>(_ keyValue:(Element)->T) -> [Element]
   { 
      return filterDuplicate{"\(keyValue($0))"}
   }
}

// example usage: (for a unique combination of attributes):

peopleArray = peopleArray.filterDuplicate{ ($0.name, $0.age, $0.sex) }

or...

peopleArray = peopleArray.filterDuplicate{ "\(($0.name, $0.age, $0.sex))" }
```

You don't have to bother with making values Hashable and it allows you to use different combinations of fields for uniqueness.

*Note: for a more robust approach, please see the solution proposed by Coeur in the comments below.*

[stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/1033581](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/1033581)

**[EDIT]** Swift 4 alternative

With Swift 4.2 you can use the Hasher class to build a hash much easier.  The above extension could be changed to leverage this :

```
extension Array
{
    func filterDuplicate(_ keyValue:((AnyHashable...)->AnyHashable,Element)->AnyHashable) -> [Element]
    {
        func makeHash(_ params:AnyHashable ...) -> AnyHashable
        { 
           var hash = Hasher()
           params.forEach{ hash.combine($0) }
           return hash.finalize()
        }  
        var uniqueKeys = Set<AnyHashable>()
        return filter{uniqueKeys.insert(keyValue(makeHash,$0)).inserted}     
    }
}
```

The calling syntax is a little different because the closure receives an additional parameter containing a function to hash a variable number of values (which must be Hashable individually)

```
peopleArray = peopleArray.filterDuplicate{ $0($1.name, $1.age, $1.sex) }
```

It will also work with a single uniqueness value (using $1 and ignoring $0).

```
peopleArray = peopleArray.filterDuplicate{ $1.name }
```

Comment: This could give random results depending on the behavior of `"\()"`, as it may not gives you unique values like conforming to `Hashable` should. Example, if your elements conform to `Printable` by all returning the same `description`, then your filtering fails.

Comment: Agreed. Selection of the fields (or formula) that will produce the desired uniqueness pattern will have to take this into account.  For many use cases, this provides a simple  ad-hoc solution that requires no alteration of the element's class or struct.

Comment: @AlainT. Don't do this, really. String's purpose is not to be some ghetto ad-hoc key generation mechanism. Just constrain `T` to being `Hashable`.

Comment: @Alexander I've applied this idea in a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/1033581

Comment: Perfect answer as i want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

As was noted at WWDC 2021, Swift has community-developed Algorithms, Collections, and Numerics Packages. The Algorithms package features a `uniqued()` algorithm.

These are not yet part of the Swift Standard library. You can currently download them from Apple's Github page and/or install them via Swift Package Manager.

**WWDC Video:**

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10256/

**Github page:**

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms

**`uniqued()` and `uniqued(on:)` documentation:**

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Unique.md

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: How do I do this in iOS?

Answer (score 5):

1. First add all the elements of an array to NSOrderedSet.
2. This will remove all the duplicates in your array.
3. Again convert this orderedset to an array.

Done....

Example

```
let array = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,6,8]

let orderedSet : NSOrderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: array)

let arrayWithoutDuplicates : NSArray = orderedSet.array as NSArray
```

output of arrayWithoutDuplicates - [1,2,4,6,8]

Answer (score 4):

You can use directly a set collection to remove duplicate, then cast it back to an array

```
var myArray = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
var mySet = Set<Int>(myArray)

myArray = Array(mySet) // [2, 4, 60, 6, 15, 24, 1]
```

Then you can order your array as you want

```
myArray.sort{$0 < $1} // [1, 2, 4, 6, 15, 24, 60]
```

Comment: "Then you can order your array as you want" What if I want the same ordering as from the original array? It's not that easy.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need values sorted, this works (Swift 4)

`let sortedValues = Array(Set(array)).sorted()`

Comment: You loosing elements order in this case.

Comment: Not at all, that's what the `.sorted()` at the end is for. Regards.

Comment: @MauricioChirino And if your original array was `[2, 1, 1]`? It would come out `[1, 2]`, that's not ordered :p

Comment: @MauricioChirino No, it wouldn't. The correct answer would be `[2, 1]`, but this would return `[1, 2]`, which is wrong.

Comment: I think you're confusing _sorted_ with _reversed_ @Alexander.

Comment: @MauricioChirino No, I'm not. If the goal is to remove duplicate values from a sequence, while retaining the order in which elements uniquely appeared, ***this doesn't do that.*** The very clear counter example is `[2, 1, 1]`. The first appearance of unique elements, in order is `[2, 1]`. That's the correct answer. But using your (incorrect) algorithm, you get `[1, 2]`, which *is* sorted, but *is not* in the correct, original, order.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the answer. Regards @Alexander

Comment: Fails if the elements in `array` are not `Hashable`; only `Hashable` data types can be added to a Set, yet any data type can be added to an array.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that

- Uses no legacy `NS` types
- Is reasonably fast with `O(n)`
- Is concise
- Preserves element order

```swift
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    var uniqueValues: [Element] {
        var allowed = Set(self)
        return compactMap { allowed.remove($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but would only works for Hashable elements

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more succinct syntax version of [Daniel Krom's Swift 2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065542/616764), using a trailing closure and shorthand argument name, which appears to be based on [Airspeed Velocity's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27624444/616764):

```
func uniq<S: SequenceType, E: Hashable where E == S.Generator.Element>(source: S) -> [E] {
  var seen = [E: Bool]()
  return source.filter { seen.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil }
}
```

Example of implementing a custom type that can be used with `uniq(_:)` (which must conform to `Hashable`, and thus `Equatable`, because `Hashable` extends `Equatable`):

```
func ==(lhs: SomeCustomType, rhs: SomeCustomType) -> Bool {
  return lhs.id == rhs.id // && lhs.someOtherEquatableProperty == rhs.someOtherEquatableProperty
}

struct SomeCustomType {

  let id: Int

  // ...

}

extension SomeCustomType: Hashable {

  var hashValue: Int {
    return id
  }

}
```

In the above code...

`id`, as used in the overload of `==`, could be any `Equatable` type (or method that returns an `Equatable` type, e.g., `someMethodThatReturnsAnEquatableType()`). The commented-out code demonstrates extending the check for equality, where `someOtherEquatableProperty` is another property of an `Equatable` type (but could also be a method that returns an `Equatable` type).

`id`, as used in the `hashValue` computed property (required to conform to `Hashable`), could be any `Hashable` (and thus `Equatable`) property (or method that returns a `Hashable` type).

Example of using `uniq(_:)`:

```
var someCustomTypes = [SomeCustomType(id: 1), SomeCustomType(id: 2), SomeCustomType(id: 3), SomeCustomType(id: 1)]

print(someCustomTypes.count) // 4

someCustomTypes = uniq(someCustomTypes)

print(someCustomTypes.count) // 3
```

Comment: There no need to use a `Bool`, when the only value you use is `true`. You're reaching for a "unit type" (a type with only one possible value). Swift's unit type is `Void`, whose only value is `()` (a.k.a. the empty tuple). So you can just use `[T: Void]`. Though you shouldn't do that, because you've basically just invented `Set`. Use `Set` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/3141234

Answer (score 2):

here I've done some O(n) solution for objects. Not few-lines solution, but...

```
struct DistinctWrapper <T>: Hashable {
    var underlyingObject: T
    var distinctAttribute: String
    var hashValue: Int {
        return distinctAttribute.hashValue
    }
}
func distinct<S : SequenceType, T where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S,
                                                                distinctAttribute: (T) -> String,
                                                                resolution: (T, T) -> T) -> [T] {
    let wrappers: [DistinctWrapper<T>] = source.map({
        return DistinctWrapper(underlyingObject: $0, distinctAttribute: distinctAttribute($0))
    })
    var added = Set<DistinctWrapper<T>>()
    for wrapper in wrappers {
        if let indexOfExisting = added.indexOf(wrapper) {
            let old = added[indexOfExisting]
            let winner = resolution(old.underlyingObject, wrapper.underlyingObject)
            added.insert(DistinctWrapper(underlyingObject: winner, distinctAttribute: distinctAttribute(winner)))
        } else {
            added.insert(wrapper)
        }
    }
    return Array(added).map( { return $0.underlyingObject } )
}
func == <T>(lhs: DistinctWrapper<T>, rhs: DistinctWrapper<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

// tests
// case : perhaps we want to get distinct addressbook list which may contain duplicated contacts like Irma and Irma Burgess with same phone numbers
// solution : definitely we want to exclude Irma and keep Irma Burgess
class Person {
    var name: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    init(_ name: String, _ phoneNumber: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
}

let persons: [Person] = [Person("Irma Burgess", "11-22-33"), Person("Lester Davidson", "44-66-22"), Person("Irma", "11-22-33")]
let distinctPersons = distinct(persons,
    distinctAttribute: { (person: Person) -> String in
        return person.phoneNumber
    },
    resolution:
    { (p1, p2) -> Person in
        return p1.name.characters.count > p2.name.characters.count ? p1 : p2
    }
)
// distinctPersons contains ("Irma Burgess", "11-22-33") and ("Lester Davidson", "44-66-22")
```

Comment: Rather than using a `Set` with a custom `DistinctWrapper`, you should use a `Dictionary` from distinctAttributes to objects. When you follow that logic through, you would eventually end up implementing [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`]https://pastebin.com/w90pVe0p(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995340-init), which is now built into the standard library. Check out how simple this is https://pastebin.com/w90pVe0p

Answer (score 2):

I used @Jean-Philippe Pellet's answer and made an Array extension that does set-like operations on arrays, while maintaining the order of elements.

```
/// Extensions for performing set-like operations on lists, maintaining order
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
  func unique() -> [Element] {
    var seen: [Element:Bool] = [:]
    return self.filter({ seen.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil })
  }

  func subtract(takeAway: [Element]) -> [Element] {
    let set = Set(takeAway)
    return self.filter({ !set.contains($0) })
  }

  func intersect(with: [Element]) -> [Element] {
    let set = Set(with)
    return self.filter({ set.contains($0) })
  }
}
```

Comment: There no need to use a `Bool`, when the only value you use is `true`. You're reaching for a "unit type" (a type with only one possible value). Swift's unit type is `Void`, whose only value is `()` (a.k.a. the empty tuple). So you can just use `[T: Void]`. Though you shouldn't do that, because you've basically just invented `Set`. Use `Set` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/3141234

Answer (score 2):

This is just a very simple and convenient implementation. A computed property in an extension of an Array that has equatable elements.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    /// Array containing only _unique_ elements.
    var unique: [Element] {
        var result: [Element] = []
        for element in self {
            if !result.contains(element) {
                result.append(element)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
func removeDublicate (ab: [Int]) -> [Int] {
var answer1:[Int] = []
for i in ab {
    if !answer1.contains(i) {
        answer1.append(i)
    }}
return answer1
}
```

Usage:

```
let f = removeDublicate(ab: [1,2,2])
print(f)
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest

Comment: it keeps the order and gives you an array you want

Comment: This is also `O(n²)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3/ Swift 4/ Swift 5**

**Just one line code to omit Array duplicates without effecting order:**

```
let filteredArr = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: yourArray))
```

Comment: Here we are typecasting an array into Orderedset.
 Definition of "Sets" - sets allow only distinct values (It does not allow duplicates). Hence duplicates will be omitted
 As we are typecasting with NSOrderedSet hence array order will not be disturbed.

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5.7***

### Using Ordered Set

You can pass an array with repeating elements to the following ***generic function***, which processes an ordered Set and returns a new array with no duplicates.

```
import Foundation

internal func withoutDuplicates<T>(_ array: [T]) -> [T] {
    
    let orderedSet: NSMutableOrderedSet = []
    var modifiedArray = [T]()
    
    orderedSet.addObjects(from: array)
    
    for i in 0...(orderedSet.count - 1) {
        modifiedArray.append(orderedSet[i] as! T)
    }
    return modifiedArray
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["A","A","A","B","B","C","C"]
let arrayOfIntegers: [UInt8] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
let arrayOfBooleans: [Bool] = [true, false, false, true]

let ordered_01 = withoutDuplicates(arrayOfStrings)
let ordered_02 = withoutDuplicates(arrayOfIntegers)
let ordered_03 = withoutDuplicates(arrayOfBooleans)
```

Results:

```
// ordered_01  –––>  ["A","B","C"]
// ordered_02  –––>  [1, 2, 3]
// ordered_03  –––>  [true, false]
```

### Using Unordered Set

If the order of the elements in the new array doesn't really matter to you, use an unordered Set when processing. Elements' type in unordered Set must conform to [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol.

```
import UIKit

fileprivate func noDuplicates<T: Hashable>(_ array: [T]) -> [T] {
    
    var unorderedSet = Set<T>()
    var modifiedArray: [T] = []
    
    for i in 0...(array.count - 1) {
        unorderedSet.insert(array[i])
    }
    for i in unorderedSet.indices {
        modifiedArray.append(unorderedSet[i])
    }
    return modifiedArray
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let arrayOfInts: [Int] = [10, 5, 7, 200, -500, 10, 7, 5]
let arrayOfStrs: [String] = ["A","A","A","B","B","C","C"]
let arrayOfBools: [Bool] = [true, false, false, true]

let unordered_01 = noDuplicates(arrayOfInts)
let unordered_02 = noDuplicates(arrayOfStrs)
let unordered_03 = noDuplicates(arrayOfBools)
```

Results:

```
// unordered_01  –––>  [200, 7, 10, -500, 5]
// unordered_02  –––>  ["B", "C", "A"]
// unordered_03  –––>  [false, true]
```

Comment: don't force unwrap code, modifiedArray.append(orderedSet[i] as! T)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a Dictionary, because a Dictionary can only hold unique values. For example:

```
var arrayOfDates: NSArray = ["15/04/01","15/04/01","15/04/02","15/04/02","15/04/03","15/04/03","15/04/03"]

var datesOnlyDict = NSMutableDictionary()
var x = Int()

for (x=0;x<(arrayOfDates.count);x++) {
    let date = arrayOfDates[x] as String
    datesOnlyDict.setValue("foo", forKey: date)
}

let uniqueDatesArray: NSArray = datesOnlyDict.allKeys // uniqueDatesArray = ["15/04/01", "15/04/03", "15/04/02"]

println(uniqueDatesArray.count)  // = 3
```

As you can see, the resulting array will not always be in 'order'. If you wish to sort/order the Array, add this:

```
var sortedArray = sorted(datesOnlyArray) {
(obj1, obj2) in

    let p1 = obj1 as String
    let p2 = obj2 as String
    return p1 < p2
}

println(sortedArray) // = ["15/04/01", "15/04/02", "15/04/03"]
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be good to offer a `uniq()` and `uniqInPlace()` function to mutate an Array by removing it's values. This works similar as the `sort()` and `sortInPlace()` function provided by Swift. Also since it's an Array it should keep it's original order of elements.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    public func uniq() -> [Element] {
        var arrayCopy = self
        arrayCopy.uniqInPlace()
        return arrayCopy
    }

    mutating public func uniqInPlace() {
        var seen = [Element]()
        var index = 0
        for element in self {
            if seen.contains(element) {
                removeAtIndex(index)
            } else {
                seen.append(element)
                index++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can only use `uniqInPlace()` on a variable Array (i.e. `var`) since you cannot mutate a constant Array (i.e. `let`).

Some usage examples:

```
var numbers = [1, 6, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5]
numbers.uniqInPlace() // array is now [1, 6, 2, 4, 5]

let strings = ["Y", "Z", "A", "Y", "B", "Y", "Z"]
let uniqStrings = strings.uniq() // uniqStrings is now ["Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
```

Comment: An `Array<Element>` is not an appropriate choice for the type of `seen`. The repeated `contains` calls (each of which is `O(n)`) makes this algorithm at least `O(n^2)`. Also, `removeAtIndex`) is also `O(n)` (because it causes every element after the remove element to have to be shifted left by 1). Instead, an algorithm like this would work better using `var seen = Set<Element>()`, and rather than "removing" elements, you "overwrite" them, by reading ahead until you see the next element that you need to keep.

Comment: That way, you keep all the elements you want, and end up with a set of empty space at the end of array that can just be trimmed in one shot

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use NSOrderedSet, that stores unique elements and preserves the elements order. Like:

```
func removeDuplicates(from items: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let uniqueItems = NSOrderedSet(array: items)
    return (uniqueItems.array as? [Int]) ?? []
}

let arr = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
removeDuplicates(from: arr)
```

Comment: I wonder how this performance compares to the better answers on here. Have you compared?

Answer (score 1):

I think this the better way with knowing the logic itself

```
var arrayOfInts = [2, 2, 4, 4]
var mainArray = [Int]()

for value in arrayOfInts {

if mainArray.contains(value) != true  {
    
    mainArray.append(value)
    print("mainArray:\(mainArray)")
}}
```

Comment: This is quadratic behavior. Each iteration of your loop call contains, which itself uses a loop over all elements. Really slow.

Comment: mainArray.contains(value) == false can be simplified to mainArray.contains(value) != true

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,10,10, 12, 12, 6,6,6,7,8,8, 8, 8, 8 , 7 , 1 , 1, 2 , 9]

var newArr : [Int] = []
for n in numbers {
    if !newArr.contains(n) {
        newArr.append(n)
    }
}
```

output - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9]

The above solution maintains order but very slow as **.contains** iterates again and again.
Thus use the ordered set.

This will print the ordered array.

```
Array(NSOrderedSet.init(array: numbers))
```

output - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9]

This Will Print an unordered array.

```
let uniqueUnordered = Array(Set(numbers))
```

output - [4, 2, 1, 9, 10, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 7]

Answer (score 1):

contains checks for equality while insert checks for hash, its safest to check in the following way:

```swift
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    /// Big O(N) version. Updated since @Adrian's comment. 
    var uniques: Array {
        // Go front to back, add element to buffer if it isn't a repeat.
         var buffer: [Element] = []
         var dictionary: [Element: Int] = [:]
         for element in self where dictionary[element] == nil {
             buffer.append(element)
             dictionary[element] = 1
         }
         return buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: This might get the job done on smaller arrays, but I tried it on a large data set and it was extremely slow.

Comment: Thank you for the input!  Ah yes, the method contains makes this an O(N^2) operation...Good catch.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are collisions in the `hashValue`. Having collision should be handled by checking for equality. This is why the `Hashable` protocol inherits from `Equatable`.

Comment: Just updated to another attempt

Comment: @Adrian, can you check this one please?

Comment: @Gigisommo, is this implementation better Can you check?

Comment: @ScottyBlades this is better, but you can improve it further by using a set instead of a dictionary. In this implementation you're already using the dictionary as a set. They both have a constant lookup time and they both allow only unique keys (in the case of the dictionary) / item (in the case of the set). There is no reason to use a dictionary associated with an arbitrary integer, you can just use a set instead. But this is already an improvement and it should work in all scenarios, even with conflicting hashes. :)

Answer (score 1):

easy way to remove duplicates from array

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
mutating func removeDuplicates() {
    var result = [Element]()
    for value in self {
        if !result.contains(value) {
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    self = result
}}
```

Comment: While this method is, indeed, simple, it is really not optimal. It has quadratic algorithmic complexity because you keep looping the `result` temporary array over and over for each element of the original array.

The other solutions involving using a Set will be much faster because the `contains` lookup is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest an answer similar to [Scott Gardner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984316/1928138) but with more laconic syntax using reduce.
This solution removes duplicates from an array of custom objects (keeping the initial order)

```
// Custom Struct. Can be also class. 
// Need to be `equitable` in order to use `contains` method below
struct CustomStruct : Equatable {
      let name: String
      let lastName : String
    }

// conform to Equatable protocol. feel free to change the logic of "equality"
func ==(lhs: CustomStruct, rhs: CustomStruct) -> Bool {
  return (lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName)
}

let categories = [CustomStruct(name: "name1", lastName: "lastName1"),
                  CustomStruct(name: "name2", lastName: "lastName1"),
                  CustomStruct(name: "name1", lastName: "lastName1")]
print(categories.count) // prints 3

// remove duplicates (and keep initial order of elements)
let uniq1 : [CustomStruct] = categories.reduce([]) { $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] }
print(uniq1.count) // prints 2 - third element has removed
```

And just if you are wondering how this reduce magic works - here is exactly the same, but using more expanded reduce syntax

```
let uniq2 : [CustomStruct] = categories.reduce([]) { (result, category) in
  var newResult = result
  if (newResult.contains(category)) {}
  else {
    newResult.append(category)
  }
  return newResult
}
uniq2.count // prints 2 - third element has removed
```

You can simply copy-paste this code into a Swift Playground and play around.

Comment: For Swift 4 you need to replace `$0` with `$0.0` and `$1` with `$0.1`.

Comment: Note that prior to Swift 4 (i.e. in Swift 3) it is discouraged to use `reduce` with a mutable struct type (here it's []), as the mutability is not preserved and `reduce` is creating an overhead of copying the struct each time.

Comment: Generally you would want to encapsulate code like this into a function, rather than copy pasting it everywhere it's used. And `reduce` isn't an appropriate choice for this algorithm. It makes it  `O(n²)`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0 the simplest and fastest solution I've found to eliminate the duplicated elements while keeping the order:

```
extension Array where Element:Hashable {
    var unique: [Element] {
        var set = Set<Element>() //the unique list kept in a Set for fast retrieval
        var arrayOrdered = [Element]() //keeping the unique list of elements but ordered
        for value in self {
            if !set.contains(value) {
                set.insert(value)
                arrayOrdered.append(value)
            }
        }

        return arrayOrdered
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do the `contains` and `insert` in one shot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more flexible way to make a sequence unique with a custom matching function.

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {

    func unique(matching: (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Iterator.Element] {

        var uniqueArray: [Iterator.Element] = []
        forEach { element in
            let isUnique = uniqueArray.reduce(true, { (result, item) -> Bool in
                return result && matching(element, item)
            })
            if isUnique {
                uniqueArray.append(element)
            }
        }
        return uniqueArray
    }
}
```

Comment: That *is* an interesting demonstration of how `contains(where:)` can be implemented with only `reduce`, but in production code like this, it's better to just use `contains(where:)` directly. For one, it can short circuit the search if an element is found early on (no need to keep searching after that, but this `reduce` method does that anyway)

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest way in swift 4.2 onwards the code like below

```
let keyarray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

for  object in dataArr
{
    if !keysArray.contains(object){
        keysArray.add(object)
    }
}

print(keysArray)
```

Comment: Ooof. Don't do this. That's an `O(n^2)` algorithm (because `contains` is `O(n)`, which itself runs `n` times). And don't use NSMutableArray in Swift

Answer (score 0):

### Xcode 10.1 - **Swift 4.2 Simple and Powerful Solution**

```
func removeDuplicates(_ nums: inout [Int]) -> Int {
    nums = Set(nums).sorted()
    return nums.count
}
```

Example

```
var arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
removeDuplicates(&arr)

print(arr) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: This does not keep the original order: it applies a new order, which may or may not be the same. Even if it's the same order, it's not as performant as a solution that would simply keep the existing order without adding an extra `sorted`.

Comment: Yeah, the `sorted()` call is a totally misplaced responsibility. The caller asked for deduplication. If they also wanted sorting they can already do that themselves. I would suggest deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, it seems it can be in O(n) time as Hash map access is O(1), and filter is O(n). It also uses by closure to select property by which to make the distinction of elements in sequence.

```
extension Sequence {

    func distinct<T: Hashable>(by: (Element) -> T) -> [Element] {
        var seen: [T: Bool] = [:]
        return self.filter { seen.updateValue(true, forKey: by($0)) == nil }
    }
}
```

Comment: There no need to use a `Bool`, when the only value you use is `true`. You're reaching for a "unit type" (a type with only one possible value). Swift's unit type is `Void`, whose only value is `()` (a.k.a. the empty tuple). So you can just use `[T: Void]`. Though you shouldn't do that, because you've basically just invented `Set`. Use `Set` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/3141234 Please delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a higher-order function that has time complexity is o(n). Also, capability like the map to return any type you want.

```
extension Sequence {
    func distinct<T,U>(_ provider: (Element) -> (U, T)) -> [T] where U: Hashable {
        var uniqueKeys = Set<U>()
        var distintValues = [T]()
        for object in self {
            let transformed = provider(object)
            if !uniqueKeys.contains(transformed.0) {
                distintValues.append(transformed.1)
                uniqueKeys.insert(transformed.0)
            }
        }
        return distintValues
    }
}
```

Comment: This does two hashing operations per element, which is unnecessary. `insert` returns a tuple that tells you whether the element was already there, or was added for the first time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684308/3141234 Please delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the order as well then use this

```
let fruits = ["apple", "pear", "pear", "banana", "apple"] 
let orderedNoDuplicates = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: fruits).map({ $0 as! String }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension to Array to remove duplicates and maintain the original order of elements:

```
extension Array {

    var removingDuplicates: [Element] {
        NSOrderedSet(array: self).array.compactMap({ $0 as? Element })
    }
}
```

The first occurrence of the value is kept, subsequent duplicate values are removed.

Usage:

```
let nums = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2]
nums.removingDuplicates // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using dictionary. Time: O(m+n), Space: O(m+n).

```
var array = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]

func removeDuplicate(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  var dict: [Int: Bool] = [Int: Bool]()

  for value in array { 
      dict[value] = true
  }

  return  dict.keys.map { $0 }//.sorted()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Preserve unique values and **preserve sorting** in an array.

**(using Swift 3)**

```
    var top3score: [Int] = []


    outerLoop: for i in 0..<top10score.count {
        dlog(message: String(top10score[i]))

        if top3score.count == 3 {
            break
        }

        for aTop3score in top3score {
            if aTop3score == top10score[i] {
                continue outerLoop
            }
        }

        top3score.append(top10score[i])

    }

    print("top10score is \(top10score)")  //[14, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    print("top3score is \(top3score)")   //[14, 5, 3]
```

Comment: This is a good first approach, but it's quite complex and verbose. This code does too many things (deduplicating, truncating to `3` results), and there's no easy way to reuse it without mass copy/paste. You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354989/3141234). You could then write something like `scores.uniqued().prefix(3)`. Simple!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The main points of the code above are not only to preserve unique values but also to preserve the original ordering. Using "Set" seems can't preserve the ordering. :)

Comment: Yes it can. Take a look at the answer I can. You use the set for fast answers to the question of "Have I already seen this element?"

Answer (score -1):

I've made a simple-as-possible extension for that purpose.

```swift
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    func containsHowMany(_ elem: Element) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) { $1 == elem ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
    }

    func duplicatesRemoved() -> Array {
        return self.filter { self.containsHowMany($0) == 1 }
    }

    mutating func removeDuplicates() {
        self = self.duplicatesRemoved(()
    }
}
```

You can use `duplicatesRemoved()` to get a new array, whose duplicate elements are removed, or `removeDuplicates()` to mutate itself. See:

```swift
let arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8]

let noDuplicates = arr.duplicatesRemoved()
print(arr) // [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8]
print(noDuplicates) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

arr.removeDuplicates()
print(arr) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This is also `O(n²)`.

Comment: It has 2 downvotes, actually, and idk. Probably because it's needless quadratic

Answer (score -3):

This works in Swift 4, if you do not want/need to convert the result to an Array, but can do with a Set. The result is not sorted by default, but you can do that with sorted(), which returns an array, as shown in the print statement.

```
let array = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]

var result = Set<Int>()
_ = array.map{ result.insert($0) }

print(result.sorted())  // [1, 2, 4, 6, 15, 24, 60]
```

Comment: This irreversibly loses ordering. Sorting only makes sense if your original ordering was sorted order, which isn't the case your example. Also, don't abuse `map` where `forEach` would make more sense. Even still, it could be just `let result = Set(array)`