# can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

when I try to find duplicates in array, I get the error "can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes". I find the duplicates following method.

```
    func uniq<S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S) -> [T] {
    var buffer = [T]()
    var added = Set<T>()
    for elem in source {
        if !added.contains(elem) {
            buffer.append(elem)
            added.insert(elem)
        }
    }
    return buffer
}

func filter() {
    var arrayForSearch = mp3Files as! [String]
    var filteredArray = uniq(arrayForSearch)
    println("filtered array \(filteredArray)")
}
```

The method of find duplicates I knew on this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro). I use Xcode 6 and Swift 1.2

There is the array in this code.

```
var mp3Files: Array<String!>!
func exportData() {
    var generalURL: [AnyObject]?
    var arrayFiles: Array<NSURL!>!
    var directory = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
    var urlFromDirectory = directory.first as! NSURL

    var file = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(urlFromDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles, error: nil)!
    println("file \(file)")

    mp3Files = file.map(){ $0.lastPathComponent }.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" }

  println("mp3 files  \(mp3Files)")
}
```

When I wrote this code in playground it works. 
An example

```
var array = ["Apple", "Mac", "iPhone", "iPad Air", "Apple", "Air", "Air"]
var filteredArray = Array(Set(array))

println(filteredArray)
```

How can I use it in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mp3Files: Array<String!>!
```

Wow, that's a lot of exclamation points.... They're not needed.

```
var arrayForSearch = mp3Files as! [String]
```

And the type of `mp3Files` can never be the same as `[String]`, so you can't force-cast between them (and would crash if it let you).

You're using implicitly unwrapped optionals way too often. They are only needed in some special cases. Just change `mp3Files` to `[String]` (in which case you won't need the `as!` at all; you shouldn't need `as!` very often either).

Similarly, `arrayFiles` (which you never use), should just be `[NSURL]`, not `Array<NSURL!>!`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I try same code as you given:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let strArr = ["a","b","a","d","f","f","b"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filter()
    }

    func uniq<S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S) -> [T] {
        var buffer = [T]()
        var added = Set<T>()
        for elem in source {
            if !added.contains(elem) {
                buffer.append(elem)
                added.insert(elem)
            }
        }
        return buffer
    }

    func filter() {
        var arrayForSearch = strArr
        var newArr = uniq(arrayForSearch)
        println("filtered array \(newArr)")
    }
}
```

And `OutPut` in console:

```
filtered array [a, b, d, f]
```

My be there is a problem when you are casting your array to `[String]` so check it once again.

Comment: There isn't a problem with casting because mp3Files is Array<String!>!

Comment: Try to change it's type like `[String]`

Comment: So I changed it in here var arrayForSearch = mp3Files as! [String]

Comment: can you change the type of `mp3Files ` when you declaring it?