# Why isn't unsafeBitCast a compiler error?

Tags: swift, swift2

The general question of why the following code fails has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717580) already. But my question is, if it's never possible, why isn't this a compiler error?

Here's a minimal example: I can define this function and the compiler doesn't complain even though the unsafeBitCast will always fail:

```
func foo() -> [Int] {
    let arr: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    guard let barr = arr as? [Int] else { return [] }
    return barr
}
```

This doesn't fail until we actually try to call `foo()` at runtime.

Comment: I don't see how the question of why this crashes has been answered already by the linked thread. An even more minimal example of this runtime crash is `[Int?](count: 2, repeatedValue: 1) is [Int]`, which I believe to be strange. In the linked thread, OP attempts to use forced unwrapping (`... !`) and forced casting (`as!`), whereas here, we can reproduce the problem simply by using `is` type representation check. I might be wrong, but as far as I'm concerned, this looks like bug-like behaviour due to some backend sugar (bitcast magic).

Comment: @dfri, please, check my 'answer', even though there are more only notes, than real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a compiler bug, because [Int] is not subtype of [Int?] So, your code shouldn't compile without any error. However, next code should work as expected

```
let i: [Int?] = [1,2,3]
let d: [Double?] = [1,2,3]

func foo<T>(arr:[T?]?) -> [T] {
    guard let barr = arr where T.self == Int.self else { return [] }
    return barr.flatMap{ $0 }
}

print(foo(i), foo(i).dynamicType)
print(foo(d), foo(d).dynamicType)
/*
 [1, 2, 3] Array<Int>
 [] Array<Double>
 */
```

Please, fill the bug report! More interestingly next code doesn't compile

```
let j = [Optional(1),Optional(2)] as? [Int]
```

but

```
let j = [Optional(1),Optional(2)]
let k = j as? [Int]
```

compile and crash ...

```
let arr0:[Int?]? = [1,2,3]

if let r = arr0 where r.dynamicType == [Int].self {
    print(r, r.dynamicType)
} else {
    print("not [Int]")
}
// prints 
// not [Int]

// but
func foo()->[Int] {
    let arr0:[Int?]? = [1,2,3]
    if let r = arr0 where r.dynamicType == [Int].self {
        print(r, r.dynamicType)
        // !!!!! ERROR !!!!!
        // next line doesn't compile wihout flatMap !!!!
        //
        // error: cannot convert return expression of type '[Int?]' to return type '[Int]'
        //
        // even though that it is clear from the where clause that r type must be [Int]
        return r.flatMap{ $0 }
    } else {
        print("arr0 is not [Int]")
        return []
    }
}
foo() // [] and prints: arr0 is not [Int]
```

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug; as I mentioned in my comment, probably due to some backend conversion magic. If possible, I'd also include in the answer that we see the same runtime exception even when we only test type representation using `is`. Type casting is notorious for yielding runtime errors, but just doing a type representation check (`is`) is generally more innocent, and should really not cause a runtime exception (or attempted bitcast) like this. E.g., in your `j` and `k` example above (`let j = [Optional(1),Optional(2)]`), `let k = j is [Int]` yields the same runtime crash.

Comment: yes, compare one line and two lines version of the same :-) first doesn't compile, which is fine, the second crash ... :-)

Comment: Seems like this bug has [already been reported here (SR-869)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-869).