# How i can add all phone contact to tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview, contacts

How can I import all the contacts from the phone book in your application. and so that we could gain the imported contacts.

Comment: Andrei see this perfect answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261248/how-to-impliment-search-bar-in-table-view-for-contacts-in-ios/38264318#38264318

Comment: Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595631/display-all-contacts-from-the-ios-device-in-custom-table-viewcontoller-when-cont/35603499#35603499

Comment: I have given the tried and worked solution there.Both will work perfectly.

Comment: @user3182143 ok, i can try

Comment: Andrei brother check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Impliment Search bar in Table view for Contacts in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261248/how-to-impliment-search-bar-in-table-view-for-contacts-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrei brother if you have not got answer still,I give you answer.I tried and got the solution.It works fine.

> The AddressBookUI framework is deprecated in iOS 9, so we need to use Contact Framework.

First I set or hook up the tableView using XIB or Storyboard for showing contacts.

> Must import the **Contacts framework**

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h> 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewShowContacts;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrayContacts;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableViewShowContacts;



- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   arrayContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [self getAuthorizationandContact];
   //Register the cell
   [tableViewContactData registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
   [self.view addSubview:tableViewShowContacts];
}

-(void)fetchContactsandAuthorization
{
    // Request authorization to Contacts
   CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
   [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
   if (granted == YES)
   {
      //keys with fetching properties
      NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
      NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
      NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
      NSError *error;
      NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
      if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
      } else {
        NSString *phone;
        NSString *fullName;
        NSString *firstName;
        NSString *lastName;
        UIImage *profileImage;
        NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts)
        {
            // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
            firstName = contact.givenName;
            lastName = contact.familyName;
            if (lastName == nil) {
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
            }else if (firstName == nil){
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
            }
            else{
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
            }
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
            if (image != nil) {
                profileImage = image;
            }else{
                profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
            }
            for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers)
            {
                phone = [label.value stringValue];
                if ([phone length] > 0) {
                    [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                }
            }
            NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
            [arrayContacts addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"]]];
            NSLog(@"The contacts are - %@",arrayContacts);
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableViewShowContacts reloadData];
        });
      }
    }
 }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 #pragma mark - UITableView Data Source Methods

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return  arrayContacts.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static  NSString *strCell = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = arrayContacts[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }
```

The printed results of Contacts are

```
 The contacts  are - (
 "John Appleseed",
 "Kate Bell",
 "Anna Haro",
 "Daniel Higgins",
 "David Taylor",
 "Hank Zakroff"
 )
```