# Get Distinct Members of an Array by property

Tags: swift, filter, distinct-values

I have an array 
Contract object contains:

```
String:id
String:value
```

Array is:

```
contract1 = Contract.new()
contract1.id = 2
contract1.value = "Apple"

contract2 = Contract.new()
contract2.id = 2
contract2.value = "Pen"

contract3 = Contract.new()
contract3.id = 1
contract3.value = "Pineapple"


array = [Contract1, Contract2, Contract3]
```

I would to find out the list of contracts whose IDs are distinct.

I want to have a solution that doesn't make me change the implementation of my object (overriding the isEqual method etc) since I will be using it for more than one object through out my code.

Desired result:

`[contract1, contract3]` or `[contract2, contract3]`

Ideally, an extension with additionally a method to only return the values that are being made distinct:

Desired result: `[2, 1]`

I tried a couple of approaches from similar questions but either the answers are outdated or doesn't fit my need.

Comment: With the new information, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307188/removing-duplicates-from-array-of-custom-objects-swift, but still, a duplicate.

Comment: The second question is easily handled with `map`