# How to remove duplicates data from tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

Im fetching post data from Firestore and displaying in tableview.Im trying to implement Follow feature and after fetching data of following post data gets duplicated.

**getPostData(name:String,uid:String,img:String,followingId:String)** this function is used to get post data from firebase

```
var postArray = [postData]()

    func getPostData(name:String,uid:String,img:String,followingId:String) {
        FirebaseReference(.Post).getDocuments{(snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Document Error: ", error!)
            } else {
                if let doc = snapshot, doc.isEmpty == false {
                    print("Post Document is present.")
                    let desc = doc.documents
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
                    self.postArray.removeAll()
                    for item in desc
                    {
                        let post = item.data()
                        let puid = item.documentID
                        
                        let title = post["title"] as! String
                        let audioDuration = post["audioDuration"] as! String
                        let audioUrl = post["audioUrl"] as! String
                        let date = post["date"] as! String
                        let postId = post["postId"] as! String
                        let userId = post["userId"] as! String
                        let emoji = post["emoji"] ?? ""
                        let feeling = post["feeling"] ?? ""
                        
                        FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Like").getDocuments{(snapshot1,error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("Document Error: ", error!)
                            } else {
                                
                                if let doc1 = snapshot1, doc1.isEmpty == false
                                {
                                    let likecount = snapshot1?.count ?? 0
                                    let desc1 = doc1.documents
                                    var likeByUserId : String?
                                    var likeId : String?
                                    
                                    for item in desc1 {
                                        likeByUserId = item["likedCommentToUserId"] as? String
                                        likeId = item["likeCommentByUserId"] as? String
                                    }
                                    
                                    FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Comment").getDocuments{(snapshot2,error) in
                                        if error != nil {
                                            print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                        } else {
                                            
                                            if let doc2 = snapshot2, doc2.isEmpty == false
                                            {
                                                let commentCount = snapshot2?.count ?? 0
                                              
                                                FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Report").getDocuments{(snapshot3,error) in
                                                    
                                                    if error != nil {
                                                        print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                                    } else {
                                                        
                                                        if let doc3 = snapshot3, doc3.isEmpty == false
                                                        {
                                                            let reportCount = snapshot3?.count ?? 0
                                                            let desc2 = doc3.documents
                                                            
                                                            var reportByUserId : String?
                                                            
                                                            for item in desc2 {
                                                                reportByUserId = item["userId"] as? String
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: likecount, commentCount: commentCount, reportCount: reportCount, img: img, likedByUserId:likeByUserId, likedId: likeId, reportByUserId: reportByUserId,followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                                
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: likecount, commentCount: commentCount,reportCount: 0, img: img, likedByUserId:likeByUserId, likedId: likeId, reportByUserId: "NA",followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Report").getDocuments{(snapshot3,error) in
                                                    
                                                    if error != nil {
                                                        print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                                    } else {
                                                        
                                                        if let doc3 = snapshot3, doc3.isEmpty == false
                                                        {
                                                            let reportCount = snapshot3?.count ?? 0
                                                            let desc2 = doc3.documents
                                                            
                                                            var reportByUserId : String?
                                                            
                                                            for item in desc2 {
                                                                reportByUserId = item["userId"] as? String
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: likecount, commentCount: 0,reportCount: reportCount, img: img, likedByUserId: likeByUserId, likedId: likeId, reportByUserId: reportByUserId,followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: likecount, commentCount: 0,reportCount: 0, img: img, likedByUserId: likeByUserId, likedId: likeId, reportByUserId: "NA",followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   
                                    FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Comment").getDocuments{(snapshot,error) in
                                        if error != nil {
                                            print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                        } else {
                                            
                                            if let doc2 = snapshot, doc2.isEmpty == false
                                            {
                                                let commentCount = snapshot?.count ?? 0
                                                
                                                FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Report").getDocuments{(snapshot3,error) in
                                                    
                                                    if error != nil {
                                                        print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                                    } else {
                                                        
                                                        if let doc3 = snapshot3, doc3.isEmpty == false
                                                        {
                                                            let reportCount = snapshot3?.count ?? 0
                                                            let desc2 = doc3.documents
                                                            
                                                            var reportByUserId : String?
                                                            
                                                            for item in desc2 {
                                                                reportByUserId = item["userId"] as? String
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: 0, commentCount: commentCount,reportCount: reportCount, img: img, likedByUserId: "NA", likedId: "NA", reportByUserId: reportByUserId,followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                           
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: 0, commentCount: commentCount,reportCount: 0, img: img, likedByUserId: "NA", likedId: "NA", reportByUserId: "NA",followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                FirebaseReference(.Post).document(puid).collection("Report").getDocuments{(snapshot3,error) in
                                                    
                                                    if error != nil {
                                                        print("Document Error: ", error!)
                                                    } else {
                                                        
                                                        if let doc3 = snapshot3, doc3.isEmpty == false
                                                        {
                                                            let reportCount = snapshot3?.count ?? 0
                                                            let desc2 = doc3.documents
                                                           
                                                            var reportByUserId : String?
                                                           
                                                            for item in desc2 {
                                                                reportByUserId = item["userId"] as? String
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: 0, commentCount: 0,reportCount: reportCount, img: img, likedByUserId: "NA", likedId: "NA", reportByUserId: reportByUserId,followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            
                                                            if userId == uid
                                                            {
                                                                let object = postData(audioDuration: audioDuration, audioUrl: audioUrl, date: date, postId: postId, title: title, userId: userId, name: name, emoji: emoji as? String, feeling: feeling as? String, likecount: 0, commentCount: 0,reportCount: 0, img: img, likedByUserId: "NA", likedId: "NA", reportByUserId: "NA",followingId: followingId)
                                                                self.postArray.append(object)
                                                            
                                                                self.postArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from:$0.date ?? "")?.compare(dateFormatter.date(from:$1.date ?? "")!) == .orderedDescending })
                                                                self.voicebookTableView.reloadData()
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There is parameter name,uid,img and followingId getting from Firestore Users Collection
Using this method **getUsersDataFromFirebase()**

```
func getUsersDataFromFirebase()
    {
        FirebaseReference(.Users).getDocuments{(snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Document Error: ", error!)
            } else {
                if let doc = snapshot, doc.isEmpty == false {
                    print("User Document is present.")
                    let desc = doc.documents
                    self.postArray.removeAll()
                    for item in desc
                    {
                        let user = item.data()
                        let name = user["name"] as! String
                        let uid = user["userID"] as! String
                        let img = user["imgUrl"] as? String
                        let date = user["date"] as! String
                        let gender = user["gender"] as? String
                        let location = user["location"] as! String
                        
                        FirebaseReference(.Users).document(FUser.currentUser()?.userID ?? "").collection("Following").getDocuments{(snapshot1,error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("Document Error: ", error!)
                            } else {
                                if let doc1 = snapshot1, doc1.isEmpty == false {
                                    let data = doc1.documents
                                    
                                    var followingid = ""
                                    self.postArray.removeAll()
                                    for newitem in data
                                    {
                                        let value = newitem.data()
                                        followingid = value["followedToUserId"] as? String ?? ""
                                        self.getPostData(name: name, uid: uid, img: img ?? "",followingId: followingid )
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    self.getPostData(name: name, uid: uid, img: img ?? "",followingId:"NA")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if uid == FUser.currentUser()?.userID
                        {
                            let user1 = FUser(date: date, gender: gender ?? "",imgUrl: img ?? "",location: location, name: name, status: true, userID:"\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")")
                            user1.saveUserLocally()
                            
                            let pimg = URL(string: img ?? "")
                            self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: pimg, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "demouser.png"))
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("User Document is not present.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Im getting output like in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHaC7.png)

I have tried many times but my data still getting duplicates and I don't know where I'm doing wrong please can someone help me out with this issue.

Thank You

Comment: Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307188/removing-duplicates-from-array-of-custom-objects-swift

Comment: I had already tried this but its not working

Comment: @AryanVishwakarma have you tried with Set. if you tried and still facing issue then your every object in array is different. i.e. any property of object is different than others

Comment: Im using struct and Set is not working and exactly where should I write Set as I'm appending data on different different conditions @Rahul Phate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is continuous initialization.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        var cellText : String = ""
        if appDelegate.codeList.count == 0 {
            
            return cell
            
        }
      
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if indexPath.row < appDelegate.codeList.count {
                cellText = appDelegate.codeList[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
            }
            
        }
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellText
        
        return cell
    }
```