# Swift: Remove duplicates from a multidimensional array

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in swift like this:

```
arr = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

How do I remove duplicates from this array so that my final array is:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

I'm a swift newbie. I know I can write a function to remove the dupes, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this directly.

Comment: `let filteredArray = Array(NSSet(array: array as NSArray as! [NSObject]))
` from this answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42921829/4475605