# Get Distinct Value based on "id" Paramerter in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

//this is my model

```
struct RestaurantItem : Codable {
        
    var v : Int?
    var id : String = ""
    let addOnList : [AddOnList]? 
    var createdAt : String = ""
    var orderType : Int?
    var productId : ProductId?
    var quantity : Int?
    var restaurantId : String = ""
    var specialInstructions : String = ""
    var updatedAt : String = ""
    var userId : String = ""
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case v = "__v"
        case id = "_id"
        case addOnList = "addOnList"
        case createdAt = "createdAt"
        case orderType = "orderType"
        case productId = "productId"
        case quantity = "quantity"
        case restaurantId = "restaurantId"
        case specialInstructions = "specialInstructions"
        case updatedAt = "updatedAt"
        case userId = "userId"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        v = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .v)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) ?? ""
        if (try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .addOnList)) == nil {
            self.addOnList = try values.decodeIfPresent([AddOnList].self, forKey: .addOnList)
        } else {
            self.addOnList = nil
        }
        createdAt = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .createdAt) ?? ""
        orderType = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .orderType)
        quantity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .quantity)
        restaurantId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .restaurantId) ?? ""
        specialInstructions = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .specialInstructions) ?? ""
        updatedAt = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .updatedAt) ?? ""
        userId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .userId) ?? ""
        
        if (try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .productId)) == nil {
            self.productId = try values.decodeIfPresent(ProductId.self, forKey: .productId)
        } else {
            self.productId = nil
        }
    }
    }
```

Decalare in viewcontroller

```
 var restaurantItems : [RestaurantItem]?
```

// this array contain dublicate value based on "`id`", How can i get a new array without replcate data

Comment: Why do you have duplicate? The server responds duplicates? Or do you append too many times, and you obtains duplicate? You could create a dictionary base on the id, and then retrieve the value. But is the order  important to you?

Comment: @Larme   Server provide duplicate data. I know its a server side fault but now no one there to change this data replication . I have to manage it on my own side. yes Order is important

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709066/remove-duplicate-objects-in-an-array ?

Comment: On what basis do you want to filter out the duplicate ids?

Comment: @PGDev   [0] = {
   
      productId = some {
     
         restaurantId = some {
              id = "5ed05bd5aa47246104f8c0fc"
             PName = “food”
         }
     
    }
}


[1] =  {
   
      productId = some {
     
         restaurantId = some {
              id = "5ed05bd5aa47246104f8c0fc"
PName = “drink”
         }
     
    }
}

Because id is same so i want consider it only 1 not 2. because Restaurant id is same for both so they are product of same Restaurant

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`** to filter out the duplicate values, i.e.

```
if let items = restaurantItems {
    let arr = Dictionary(grouping: items){ $0.id }.values.first.flatMap{ $0 }
    print(arr)
}
```

Comment: Author in comments: " yes Order is important ", I know, that "detail"  should be in the question.

Comment: if let items = self.restaurantItems {
                            self.arrRestaurant = Dictionary(grouping: items){ $0.productId?.restaurantId?.id }.values.first.flatMap{ $0 }
                            print(self.arrRestaurant)
                        }

Comment: restaurantId = some {
  
        id = "5ed05bd5aa47246104f8c0fc"

Comment: this is is repeated . 3 times . But ineed a single result

Comment: @PGDev   if let items = self.restaurantItems { self.arrRestaurant = Dictionary(grouping: items){ $0.productId?.restaurantId?.id }.values.first.flatMap{ $0 } print(self.arrRestaurant) }.  its contain all the values not the unique value

Answer (score 0):

If you struct conforms to the protocol Hashable and use use the id as the hash value. You can use this nice extension to give you an unique array.

```
    extension Array where Element : Hashable {
        var unique: [Element] {
            return Array(Set(self))
        }
    }
```