# equivalent of Java LinkedHashSet in Swift

Tags: swift, linkedhashset

In java we have:

```
private Set<AutoComplete> hashList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

and:

```
public class AutoComplete {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    //...geters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof AutoComplete) {
            AutoComplete autoComplete = (AutoComplete) o;
            if (name.equals(autoComplete.name) && id.equals(autoComplete.id))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        int hashMultiplikator = 79;
        try {
            hash = hashMultiplikator * hash
                    + getId().hashCode();
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            MLogger.logException("autocomplete id can't be null", e);
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Then when you add items to *hashList* , duplicate values wont be allowed and list is sort.

So my questions is how to do this in Swift?!

I already saw [Does there exist within Swift's API an easy way to remove duplicate elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25739498/3472667)

and when I pass array of AutoComplete to func uniq ,

```
var namesAndIds : [AutoComplete] = []
```

(for remove duplicates:)

```
namesAndIds.appendContentsOf(SingletonMappingContacts.sharedInstance.autoComplete)
namesAndIds = uniq(namesAndIds)

func uniq<S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S) -> [T] {
        var buffer = [T]()
        var added = Set<T>()
        for elem in source {
            if !added.contains(elem) {
                buffer.append(elem)
                added.insert(elem)
            }
        }
        return buffer
    }
```

I've got this :
*value of type AutoComplete has no member elemet*

AutoComplete:

```
class AutoComplete{
    var id : String
    var name : String
    init(id: String,name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Show your Swift code.

Comment: How is AutoComplete defined? – As always, a (small) *self-contained* example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @MartinR agian edited

Comment: `uniq()` requires that the array (or sequence) elements are `Hashable`.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079141/swift-set-of-structure-types, which shows how `Hashable` can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

For One whom like to know, I ended up avoiding `duplicate insertion issue` like below.
But **THIS WONT BE SORTED LIKE LinkedHashSet**  So problem still exist!

i've created

```
var namesAndIds = Set<AutoComplete>()
var finalAutoCompleteList = [AutoComplete]()
```

then corrected AutoComplete class:

```
public class AutoComplete:NSObject{
    var id : String
    var name : String
    init(id: String,name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
    override public func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? AutoComplete {
            return id == object.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    override public var hash: Int {
        return id.hashValue
    }

}
```

and finally added Set to Array

```
finalAutoCompleteList = Array(namesAndIds)
```

Answer (score -2):

In Swift you can use [`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).

As in the documentation:

> A set stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with no
>   defined ordering. You can use a set instead of an array when the order
>   of items is not important, or when you need to ensure that an item
>   only appears once.

A type must be hashable in order to be stored in a set—that is, the type must provide a way to compute a hash value for itself.

Simply conform to the `Hashable` protocol from Swift’s standard library.

Then you can use it like:

```
var letters = Set<Character>()  //letters == []
letters.insert("a")             //letters == ["a"]
letters.insert("a")             //letters == ["a"] - no duplicates
```

Comment: Set is not a full equivalent of LinkedHashSet (which *preserves* the order of elements).

Comment: Absolutely correct @MartinR. But in the question he store the LinkedHashSet in a private Set<AutoComplete> and his requirements were to not allow duplicates.

Comment: If he needs a specific ordering he can always implement the LinkedHashSet by himself.

Comment: why got error in defining `Set<AutoComplete>()` ? i'm new in swift

Comment: Because AutoComplete does not conform to Hashable and Equatable