# Swift Set of Structure Types

Tags: swift, struct, set

Say I have a `struct`, which could be anything:

```
struct Cube {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var z: Int
    var width: Int
    // ...
}
```

How do I then create a `Set` of these points, such that there will be no two objects with the same properties?

```
let points: Set<Cube> = Set()
// Type ‘Cube’ does not conform to protocol ‘Hashable’
```

But it’s not immediately obvious how to implement hashable. From what I read, I need to make a hash function, but that doesn’t look easily possible with the amount of properties I have in the struct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** As of **Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.4)** the compiler can synthesize
the `==` and `hashValue` methods if all members of the struct are
`Equatable/Hashable`. Therefore is suffices to declare the conformance:

```
struct Cube: Hashable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var z: Int
    var width: Int
}
```

---

**Previous answer for older Swift versions:**

First of all, `Hashable` extends `Equatable`, so you must implement
a `==` operator which compares two values, using all properties
which uniquely identify a cube:

```
func ==(lhs: Cube, rhs: Cube) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z && lhs.width == rhs.width
}
```

The `Hashable` protocol *only* requires that

> `x == y` implies `x.hashValue == y.hashValue`

so

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return 0
}
```

would be a valid (and working)  implementation. However, this would
put all objects in the same hash bucket of a set (or dictionary),
which is not effective. A better implementation is for example

```
struct Cube: Hashable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var z: Int
    var width: Int
    
    var hashValue: Int {
        return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue ^ z.hashValue ^ width.hashValue
    }
}
```

Here the "XOR" operator `^` is chosen because it cannot overflow.
You could also use the "overflow operator" `&+`.

More sophisticated hash functions would be able to distinguish
different values better, so that the set operations become faster.
On the other hand, the computation of the hash function itself
would be slower. Therefore I would look for a "better" hash function
only if the set operations turn out to be a performance bottleneck in your program.

Comment: Good explanation! What was throwing me off is that I thought that the hashValue had to be completely unique for all structs. Seems mostly just like an optimisation! Thanks!

Comment: @JacobParker: It *cannot* be unique (and hash values usually aren't) because your struct has 2^256 possible different values, and the hash value only 2^64. Of course you can make it unique in some cases. For example, `(x << 48) &+ (y << 32) &+ (z << 16) &+ width`  if all components are restricted to 16 bits.

Comment: As var hashValue is deprecated.
There is a possibility to use:
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { 
hasher.combine(x)
hasher.combine(y)
hasher.combine(z)
hasher.combine(width)
 }

Comment: @RomanMykitchak: You are completely right. But with the current Swift (and in this particular case) you don't have to implement the hash function because the compiler can synthesize it. – I have moved the newer solution to the top of the answer in order to avoid possible confusion. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Implementing `Hashable` protocol consists of two things. First is implementing `hashValue` and second one is implementing equality operator.

To have working `Hashable` protocol important part is equality operator. It has to be implemented in a way that returns true only and only then if two structures contain same values.

On the other hand your `hashValue` implementation can return literally anything as long as same structure will always return same value.

The only thing that `hashValue` influences is how fast will your code work, because when you add or look up for values, first code that will run is `hashValue`. If `hashValue` returns same value for two structures, then equality between them will be determined by calling equality operator that would otherwise be skipped.

```
struct Cube: Hashable {

    // satisfy Hashable requirement
    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            // you can return any integer here
            return x &+ y &+ z &+...
            // or even the same one for all structs
            return 0
        }
    }
}

// satisfy Equatable requirement
func ==(lhs: Cube, rhs: Cube) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y .....
}
```

Comment: Remark: `x+y+z` can overflow, causing a runtime error. (+1) though, good explanation!