# Unique array of objects

Tags: swift, list, unique

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var persons = [Person]()
```

And a person contains this:

```
id : Int
name : String
age : Int
gender : String
```

In my persons list I have multiple persons, but how do I sort this list on **unique names**?

I found this `let unique = Array(Set(originals))` but it does not seem to work on a list of objects, I want to keep all the information of the object.

If my list contains these rows:

```
Adam, Adam, John, John, Michael, Nick, Tony
```

I only want to show:

```
Adam, John, Michael, Nick Tony
```

And I still want to be able to get Adams age for example.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Person declaration

```
import Foundation

public class Person : NSObject {
    var id = ""
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    var gender = ""
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

Comment: You need to make your class Person Equatable and then you can use this extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro/34712330?s=1|0.1796#34712330

Comment: @LeoDabus, I have done that now but I´m not sure how to filter the list now.

Comment: `func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}`

Comment: Just use `yourArray.orderedSetValue`

Comment: What does *sorting on unique names* mean? Does it mean taking out duplicate records and then sorting on name field?

Comment: @ozgur, remove all duplicate names from the list

Comment: @user5855868 please give a minimal, complete, and verifiable example about what kind of result you want your code to produce.

Comment: @LeoDabus, no not yet. the `orderedSetValue`do I need an extension for that?

Comment: I have posted the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro/34712330?s=1%7C0.1796%2334712330

Comment: `extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    var orderedSetValue: Array  {
        return reduce([]){ $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] }
    }
}`

Comment: Yes missed the link, now I have added the extension and added the func == to my Person class, but it´s still the same it does not remove duplicates. The list I get from the database `s` does contain 50 records and `let persons = s.orderedSetValue` does also return 50 records.

Comment: @user5855868 I need to see your Person declaration

Comment: @LeoDabus check update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122634/discussion-between-user5855868-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this extension to return an ordered set from your people array.

```
extension Collection where Element: Hashable {
    var orderedSet: [Element] {
        var set: Set<Element> = []
        return reduce(into: []){ set.insert($1).inserted ? $0.append($1) : ()  }
    }
}
```

---

You will also have to make your Person class Equatable:

```
func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
} 

class Person: Equatable { 
    let id: String 
    let name: String 
    init(id: String, name: String) { 
        self.id = id 
        self.name = name 
    } 
}
```

---

Testing

```
let person1 = Person(id: "1", name: "Adam") 
let person2 = Person(id: "1", name: "Adam") 
let person3 = Person(id: "2", name: "John") 
let person4 = Person(id: "2", name: "John") 
let person5 = Person(id: "3", name: "Michael") 
let person6 = Person(id: "4", name: "Nick") 
let person7 = Person(id: "5", name: "Tony") 
let people = [person1,person2,person3,person4,person5,person6,person7] 
people.orderedSet //[{id "1", name "Adam"}, {id "2", name "John"}, {id "3", name "Michael"}, {id "4", name "Nick"}, {id "5", name "Tony"}]
```

Comment: He has added you on Skype now Leo, have you seen it?

Comment: I will check it