# How to remove duplicates of lines of a String in Swift without lost their order?

Tags: swift, string, duplicates, lines

I would like to remove duplicates of lines in a string with Swift 3. I got to do it but unfortunately at the end of the process the lines lost the order. Here is my code:

```
// string with 7 lines and 2 duplicates (MacBook and Mac mini)
var str = "MacBook\nMacBook Pro\nMacPro\nMacBook\niMac\nMac mini\nMac mini"

var components = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
print(components)

// remove duplicates: first by converting to a Set
// and then back to Array (found in iSwift.org)
components = Array(Set(components))
print(components)

let newStr = components.joined(separator: "\n")
print(newStr)
```

EDIT: When removing duplicates, I prefer to keep the first one not the last one.

Comment: You can use [the approach shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25739498/2976878) in order to maintain order.

Comment: When removing duplicates, do you wish to keep the first one or the last one?

Comment: `let newStr = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines).reduce([]){
        $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
}.joined(separator: "\n")`

Comment: @maddy, right question, I wish to keep the first one, I will add this info in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking @LeoDabus' comment…

```
let str = "MacBook\nMacBook Pro\nMacPro\nMacBook\niMac\nMac mini\nMac mini"
let components = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

let depDuped = components.reduce([]) {
    $0.0.contains($0.1) ? $0.0 : $0.0 + [$0.1]
}.joined(separator: "\n")
```

If duplicates can occur elsewhere in the string (so `"A\nB\nA"` would be unchanged), then

```
let depDuped = components.reduce([]) {
    $0.0.last == $0.1 ? $0.0 : $0.0 + [$0.1]
}.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you for this answer and the other comments.

Comment: I could have sworn that I wrote it that way but it didn't work - I guess I fat fingered it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSOrderedSet.

```
var str = "MacBook\nMacBook Pro\nMacPro\nMacBook\niMac\nMac mini\nMac mini"

var components = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
print(components)

let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: components)
components = orderedSet.array as! [String]
print(components)

let newStr = components.joined(separator: "\n")
print(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 Update** from @ashley-mills

```swift
let str = "MacBook\nMacBook Pro\nMacPro\nMacBook\niMac\nMac mini\nMac mini"
let components = str.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

let depDuped = components.reduce([]) {
    $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
}.joined(separator: "\n")
```