# 'NSSet' Order change in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsset

I have an array of dictionary called `'arrAllCustomer'`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:arrAllCustomer] allObjects]];
```

After executing above line the array order is changed.

Can anyone know why order is changed?

Comment: "Does anyone know why did the order change?" - because `NSSet` does not have any order whatsoever. The only container that retains the order of elements in `NSArray`

Comment: Because NSSet is unordered

Comment: to maintain order you need to use Array.

Comment: But everytime a lastobject goes to first position remaining as well.why this happens?

Comment: No one can predict the order in `NSSet`, so you can't rely on last object going to first position all the time

Answer (score 2):

`NSSet` is not supposed to retain order.

From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset):

> The NSSet, 
>   NSMutableSet
>   , and 
>   NSCountedSet
>    classes declare the programmatic interface to an **unordered** collection of objects.

If you want to retain the order of objects, work with [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray?language=objc):

> NSArray and its subclass 
>   NSMutableArray
>    manage **ordered** collections of objects called arrays. NSArray creates static arrays, and NSMutableArray creates dynamic arrays. You can use arrays when you need an ordered collection of objects.

If you want to remove duplicate objects from the array, you can write a function yourself. An example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array):

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
/// Array containing only _unique_ elements.
var unique: [Element] {
    var result: [Element] = []
    for element in self {
        if !result.contains(element) {
            result.append(element)
        }
    }

    return result
}
}
```

Comment: What i do if i have duplicate records?

Comment: You can remove the duplicate records maintaining the order