# Remove duplicate values in a tuple array

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project in Swift 3 where I have a tuple array with duplicate values is there a way to save it to a NSSet or to avoid replicating the same value. The structure of my tuple array as follow.

```
var selectedSongList : [(title: String, healerName: String, trackUrl: String, trackID: String, imageUrl: String)] = []
```

Thus later I'm using this to poplate my UITableView

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array

Comment: a code snippet would much appreciate

Comment: make a struct that conforms to equatable

Comment: how do you do it with the code. Can you share a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

**Solution 1**

You can create a structure and it should confirm to Hashable and equatable some thing like this

```
struct Post: Hashable, Equatable {
let id: String
var hashValue: Int { get { return id.hashValue } }
}

func ==(left:Post, right:Post) -> Bool {
return left.id == right.id
}
```

and to remove your object you can do like this

`let uniquePosts = Array(Set(posts))`

**Solution 2**

Create a set out of your array and then make it back to array.

Answer (score 0):

Edit func `static func ==` in `Song` struct if you have different definition about the same song

```
struct Song: Equatable {
    var title: String?
    var healerName: String?
    var trackUrl:String?
    var trackID:String?
    var imageUrl: String?

    init(_ title: String, _ healerName:String, _ trackUrl:String, _ trackID:String,_ imageUrl: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.healerName = healerName
        self.trackUrl = trackUrl
        self.trackID = trackID
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    static func == (lhs: Song, rhs: Song) -> Bool {
        return  lhs.title == rhs.title &&
                lhs.healerName == rhs.healerName && 
                lhs.trackUrl == rhs.trackUrl &&
                lhs.trackID == rhs.trackID &&
                lhs.imageUrl == rhs.imageUrl
    }
}

extension Array where Element:Equatable {
    func removeDuplicates() -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element]()

        for value in self {
            if result.contains(value) == false {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```