# Is it possible to remove duplicate values from Array with nil values

Tags: arrays, swift

Array can be any type like

```
let myArray1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, nil, 1, nil]

let myArray2 = [ 1, 2.0, 1, 3, 1.0, nil]
```

After removing **duplicate** values from the array, the new array should be:

**Output -**

```
 [ 1, 2, 3, nil ]
```

Comment: please check related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array

Comment: i tried this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array

Comment: in my array i have nil value as well

Comment: Do you want to keep the initial ordering of the Array?

Comment: yes i manage ordering also

Comment: @Bobby yes but in Set nil value not supported

Comment: Is there any special reason for keeping nil also ?. asking because there might be a better way

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes for getting nil value i perform some operation so.

Answer (score 3):

@Daniel's solution as a generic function:

```
func uniqueElements<T: Equatable>(of array: [T?]) -> [T?] {
    return array.reduce([T?]()) { (result, item) -> [T?] in
        if result.contains(where: {$0 == item}) {
            return result
        }
        return result + [item]
    }
}

let array = [1,2,3,1,2,1,3,nil,1,nil]

let r = uniqueElements(of: array) // [1,2,3,nil]
```

Comment: Alternate is that possible using extension of sequence.?

Comment: Would be interested to see that myself, I haven't found a way to express this so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this reduce to remove duplicated entries:

```
myArray.reduce([Int?]()) { (result, item) -> [Int?] in
    if result.contains(where: {$0 == item}) {
        return result
    }
    return result + [item]
}
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, nil]`

Comment: type is not specify it can be dynamic like int, double or it can be String of array

Comment: Array can be Any Type like

1) let myArray1 = [1,2,3,1,2,1,3,nil,1,nil]

or

2) let myArray2 = [1,2.0,1,3,1.0,nil]

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code, I have used NSArray after getting filtered array you can convert into swift array

```
    let arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, 8]

    let filterSet = NSSet(array: arr as NSArray as! [NSObject])
    let filterArray = filterSet.allObjects as NSArray  //NSArray
    print("Filter Array:\(filterArray)")
```

Comment: This does not preserve the order of elements.