# Merge two arrays without duplicates

Tags: swift

I have one `newArray` and one `oldArray` as follows. If newArray has anyitem which exists in the `oldArray`, then I want to delete it from `oldArray`. I could able to run two nested for loop and detect duplicates to remove, but it will be `O(n2)`. I wonder if there is a better way to handle?

I cannot use `Set`, because order needs to be kept.

> newArray = [2,4,5]
>
> oldArray = [1,2,3,5]
>
> newArray = [2,4,5,1,3] // append newArray and oldArray.

Comment: Are you simply appending `oldArray` to `newArray` but without any duplicates?

Comment: The one of the first array.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes I am trying to append `newArray` with `oldArray`. `newArray` has priority on `oldArray` in terms of duplication.

Comment: The problem description conflicts with the quoted output. The way you describe it, the output would be: `newArray = [2, 4, 5] /* no change */` `oldArray = [1, 3]` `/* mutated */` `/* That's it, there's no mention of a 3rd array */`. Please clarify.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift about removing duplicates in `O(n)` using a `Set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use `Set` after all!
Set containment is fast! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains

```
 let setFirst = Set(first)
 var merge = first
 second.forEach { v in
     if !setFirst.contains(v) {
         merge.append(v)
     }
 }
 print(merge)
```

**MINOR ADDENDUM**

For the enthusiasts of functional style and compact syntax:

```
let funcMerge = first + second.filter { !setFirst.contains($0) }
```

Comment: The latter code example is certain better. I wouldn't even entertain the first as an option for production code (good for instruction though, to show what happens "behind the scenes")