# remove duplicates from struct

Tags: ios, swift

I have some struct

```
struct WheelBrand {
var id : String?
var name : String?

mutating func removeAll() {
    self = WheelBrand()
}
```

I appended it :

```
for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"]{
  let id = subJson["make_id"].stringValue
  let name = subJson["make"].stringValue
  self.itemWheelBrand.append(WheelBrand(id: id, name: name))
  }
```

How can i remove duplicates from my struct, or i have to append it with unique values?

Comment: This has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712330/3141234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter this way after you finish appending to the array.

```
    var unique = [WheelBrand]()
    for arrValue in itemWheelBrand {
        if !unique.contains(where: { $0.id == arrValue.id }) {
            unique.append(arrValue)
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2 problems with this: 1) Using an array for uniqueness checking causes this algorithm to be `O(n^2)`, whereas a set would be `O(n)` 2) This misses a perfect chance to use `filter` or `removeAll`.