# How to remove duplicates from array using only a prefix of the values?

Tags: ios, swift

```
my response is ["9s 0.4", "Jh 0.9", "8d 0.8", "8d 0.6", "5d 0.9", "3h 0.7", "9s 0.3", "2c 0.9", "As 0.7"]
```

Values are considered equal if they start with the same first 2 characters.

I want to remove the same value. (
ex: 8d display twice I want only single 8d)

Comment: @Prasann Welcome to SO. Note that this is not a code writing service. Please edit your question, post what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Your 8d's have different values next to them.  What is the criteria for choosing one over the other?

Comment: func uniq<S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S) -> [T] {
    var buffer = [T]()
    var added = Set<T>()
    for elem in source {
        if !added.contains(elem) {
            buffer.append(elem)
            added.insert(elem)
        }
    }
    return buffer
}

let vals = [1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 24, 15, 2, 60, 15, 6]
let uniqueVals = uniq(vals) // [1, 4, 2, 6, 24, 15, 60]

Comment: check this anwer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift

Comment: do you compare just based on 2 first characters?

Comment: @ArashEtemad yes sir exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching your array items by their `prefix` (first 2 letters).  This is a little more complicated than the usual situation of handling duplicate values.

Here is a straightforward approach that uses a `Set` to keep track of the prefixes that have been seen while building the `result` array:

```
let arr = ["9s 0.4", "Jh 0.9", "8d 0.8", "8d 0.6", "5d 0.9", "3h 0.7", "9s 0.3", "2c 0.9", "As 0.7"]

// keep track of the prefixes we have seen
var prefixes = Set<String>()

// array to hold the results
var result = [String]()

for value in arr {
    // get the prefix for this value
    let prefix = String(value.prefix(2))

    // is this a new prefix?
    if !prefixes.contains(prefix) {
        // new prefix, so add value to new array
        result.append(value)

        // add prefix to our set
        prefixes.insert(prefix)
    }
}

print(result)
```

> ["9s 0.4", "Jh 0.9", "8d 0.8", "5d 0.9", "3h 0.7", "2c 0.9", "As 0.7"]

---

**Functional Approach:  Use `filter` with `Set` `.inserted`**

(As @LeoDabus demonstated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712330/1630618), you can use a `Set` with `filter` to remove custom duplicates)

You can do this with a functional approach which works in very much the same way as the approach shown above.  It uses a `Set` to keep track of the `prefixes` seen and `.inserted` to decide if a new `prefix` was added to the `Set`.  In the cases where a new `prefix` was added to `prefixes`, `filter` selects the item to be in the new `results` array.

```
let arr = ["9s 0.4", "Jh 0.9", "8d 0.8", "8d 0.6", "5d 0.9", "3h 0.7", "9s 0.3", "2c 0.9", "As 0.7"]

var prefixes = Set<Substring>()
let result = arr.filter { prefixes.insert($0.prefix(2)).inserted }
print(result)
```

> ["9s 0.4", "Jh 0.9", "8d 0.8", "5d 0.9", "3h 0.7", "2c 0.9", "As 0.7"]

Comment: `var set = Set<Substring>()` 
`let filtered = arr.filter {set.insert($0.prefix(2)).inserted}`

Comment: @LeoDabus, that is really slick. Please post that as answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712330/2303865 Done already. Works with String as well if you extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` and return `Self`