# How can I get array object of unique value using Higher Order Functions of swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Ex.

**Input:** `var array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1]`

**Output:**

> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate elements from an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1]
let output = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0})
    .values
    .sorted(by: { $0[0] < $1[0] })
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really help me lots.

Comment: Hello @vadian it's return Dictionary not array.

Comment: No, it returns array.

Comment: Yes, I am not use sorted that's why. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how this compares to `Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0 })
 .sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
 .map { $0.value }`, performance-wise

Comment: @Alexander Feel free to run a test.

Comment: @vadian I'll check it out when I have time. Side note, would you be okay if I reformatted that long line, so it fits the post better?

Comment: @Alexander Reformat how?

Comment: @vadian See my edit. Feel free to revert

Comment: @Alexander I don't mind.