# How to extend Array to dedup elements using Set?

Tags: swift

I have this function that dedups arrays by returning an array of its set.

```
func dedup<T: Hashable>(_ a: [T]) -> [T] {
    return Array(Set(a))
}

let dirty = ["apple", "apple", "kiwi", "mango"]
let clean = dedup(dirty)

print(clean)
```

However, I can't figure out how to make this an extension of `Array`.

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    static func deduped() -> Array {
        return Array(Set<Element>(self))
    }

}
```

The error I get is that `self` does not conform to expected type `Sequence`.

Comment: But note this is a poor algorithm as your array will be both deduped and shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deduped()` must be an instance method, and – more descriptive and not related to the issue – return `[Element]` rather than `Array`

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    func deduped() -> [Element] {
        return Array(Set(self))
    }
}
```

However [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift) are more efficient ways to remove duplicates, my [favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift/46354989#46354989) is

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func deduped() -> [Element] {
        var seen = Set<Element>()
        return filter{ seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you don’t have to say `Set<Element>`, just Set should be enough.

Comment: That's a pretty good favorite, I'm going to use it. But the shuffling of the order aside, the original function is as efficient as it gets, no?

Comment: Run tests of both algorithms and measure the execution time.