# Counting number of same values in a struct array

Tags: swift, struct

Had a search here but most answers seem to relate to Boolean values. I have a struct defined and initialised as below:

```
Struct Question {
   var subjectID: Int
   var questionID: Int
}

//Examples
let questionOne = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 0)
let questionTwo = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 1)
let questionThree = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 2)
let questionFour = Question(subjectID: 1, questionID: 0)

//An array populated with the above
var questions = [Question]()
```

I would like to find how to calculate:

1) The number of unique subjectID values in `questions` Array. Answer should be 2.

2) The number of questions in `questions` Array where subjectID == 0, or 1. Answer should be [3, 1].

I have explored with `.filter` and `.map` but perhaps I'm on the wrong tangent?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) you would manually filter out duplicate values. You can get an array of all the `subjectID`s with `.map` like so:

```
let subjectIDs = questions.map { $0.subjectID }
```

For 2), you can simply use the `.filter` function like so:

```
let subjectIdXCount = questions.filter { $0.subjectID == x }.count
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the first part (.map) doesn't filter out duplicates, it returns an array of [0, 0, 0, 1]. The second part works great though, thanks!

Comment: Yep, I said you will have to manually remove the duplicates. This thread might help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You should use collection's `reduce`method and increase the `initialResult` in case `nextPartialResult` meets your criteria:

```
struct Question {
   var subjectID: Int
   var questionID: Int
}
```

---

```
let questionOne = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 0)
let questionTwo = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 1)
let questionThree = Question(subjectID: 0, questionID: 2)
let questionFour = Question(subjectID: 1, questionID: 0)

let questions = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree, questionFour]

let subjectCount = questions.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.subjectID == 0 ? 1 : 0 )}

print(subjectCount)  // 3
```