# Better way of iterating through array of custom struct

Tags: swift

This is my custom data struct:

```
struct Absence {
    var type: String
    var date: TimeInterval
}
```

I have an array of this data struct like this:

```
var absences: [Absence]
```

I would like a function to return all the types of an absence. I have written this:

```
func types() -> [String] {
    var types = [String]()
    for absence in self.absences {
        if !types.contains(absence.type) {
            types.append(absence.type)
        }
    }
    return types
}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of iterating through using either map, compactMap or flatMap. I am new to mapping arrays. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Start with `absences.map { $0.type }`. Use a `Set` to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do the following:

```
var types = absences.map { $0.type }
```

If you would like to filter the types:

```
var types = absences.map { $0.type }.filter { $0.contains("-") }
```

Or if you simply want to remove all duplicates:

```
var types = Array(Set(absences.map { $0.type }))
```

Comment: Swift 5.2 or later you can use KeyPath `map(\.type)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Was actually writing the same :)

Comment: Note that using a set like this you will discard the array original order. If you would like to preserve the original order of the elements check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712330/2303865

Comment: Thank you everyone for your solutions - much appreciated!