# SwiftUI duplicate in struct and delete and merge them by quantity

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

please help me
I have following struct and photos attached.
I want to find the duplicate drinks and then delete duplicate and change the original drink quantity by adding one

```
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var price : Double
    var extra : [DrinkExtra]
    var unit : Int
    var date : Date
}
```

I have tried following code but producing error and index out of range and no magic happened.

```
    func mergeItem(){
     
        for i in cartDrinks.indices.sorted(by: { name1, name2 in
            return cartDrinks[name1].name > cartDrinks[name2].name
        }) {
            if cartDrinks[i].name == cartDrinks[i + 1].name {
                cartDrinks[i].unit += 1
                cartDrinks.remove(at: i + 1)
                print("\(cartDrinks[i].name) \(cartDrinks[i].unit)")
            } else {
                print("Nothing found")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

many thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Another approach to consider is to refactor your code so you have one type (say Drink) for the drink itself and one type (say DrinkCounter) that keep track of the units selected for a drink. This way you can leave the Drink objects untouched and only increase/decrease a counter in the DrinkCounter object when the UI changes

Comment: I have requirement string for the drinks, eg two glass of coke, one no ice and another with ice. I want if no requirement then merge together else print separate when goes to the printer.

Comment: Ok, you can also move the extras to the DrinkCounter then (maybe better name is DrinkOrder) so Drink remains immutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate elements from an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: I managed to find the duplicate value based on the post, however I don't know how to apply it to my own question . my is a struct type. this is the code from other stackoverflow post  let crossReference = Dictionary(grouping: cartDrinks) { element in
            return element.name
        }
        let duplicates = crossReference
            .filter{$1.count > 1 }
            .flatMap{($0.1)}
        print(duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have following code to complete my desired task.
many thanks

```
    func mergeItem(complete:() -> Void) {
        
        var arr = cartDrinks
        var alacartarr = cartexpress
        arr.enumerated().forEach { index,item in
            if let existIndex = arr.firstIndex(where: {item.name == $0.name }),
               existIndex != index {
                arr[existIndex].unit += arr[index].unit
                arr[index].unit = 0
        }
    }
        arr.removeAll(){$0.unit == 0}
        self.cartDrinks.removeAll()
        self.cartDrinks.append(contentsOf: arr)
        
        alacartarr.enumerated().forEach { index,value in
            if let existedIndex = alacartarr.firstIndex(where: {value.name == $0.name}),
               existedIndex != index {
                alacartarr[existedIndex].quantity += alacartarr[index].quantity
                alacartarr[index].quantity = 0
            }
        }
        alacartarr.removeAll(){$0.quantity == 0}
        cartexpress.removeAll()
        cartexpress.append(contentsOf: alacartarr)
        
        complete()
    }
```